# What about raise a bounty in a collaborative way in someone else's question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

In order to help the owner, not to hijack. The question's owner still has the power to decide. You can only contribute.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/how-about-making-it-possible-to-set-up-bounty-on-someone-elses-question

Comment: and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/contribute-to-bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

This is effectively completed, because

- bounty system is no longer tied to accepting an answer in any way
- you can issue multiple bounties on your question if necessary