# Join a bounty to increase the motivation

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More than one person should be able to offer a bounty for the same question at the same time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64768/more-than-one-person-should-be-able-to-offer-a-bounty-for-the-same-question-at-t)

There is currently a bounty running that would also provide a solution for mine problem as well. The current organizer awards 50. If I would award the same, this probably would motivate more people to work on this question.

Currently "start a bounty" seems getting not available if the bounty is already running. I would propose to replace it to "join the bounty" or the like, offering increased additional award for solution.

This possibility would also allow to contribute awarding only few reputation points (2 or 5, for instance), still adding more motivation to contribute the answer.

This makes sense in cases when the bounty task needs more time to solve so the reward is actually the price for **work**, not for attention. In such cases offering the second bounty with the same or comparable reward does not make any sense: if you offer the salary too low, you may not find the worker through ages.

Comment: But then who would get to pick who *gets* the bounty? The answer for one person might not be right for another. =)

Comment: This may indeed demotivate offering the same or more than the original author is offering, unless the original author seems trusted. However if say somebody offers a 50 bounty, one could promise an additional award of 5 delegating the right of decision to the organizer.

Comment: I like parts of your idea, but it's probably not going to be accepted because someone will come along and say "just wait for the existing bounty to time out, then award your own". =)

Comment: Just wait for the existing bounty to time out, then award your own.

Comment: The goal is to increase the motivation by offering more reward. Simply showing for longer will not motivate potential contributors more. This is important if bounty requires contributor to invest some time. If nobody cared during the first bounty, prolonging for the same reward is questionable and prolonging with now less reward does not make sense at all. Also, joining would allow to offer small reward (+1, for instance), still motivating the contributor more.

Comment: @Bart Too easy. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen Had to be done.