# Concurrent bounties in questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, active-bounties

Bounties exist to promote questions. Yet, only one bounty can be active at a time. This request outlines how we might implement having multiple bounties active at a time. Changes are as follows:

[image: A picture of a current bounty.]

So here's what bounties look like currently.

[image]

And here's an absolutely *wonderful* [Microsoft Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint) photoshopped example of how I think we could modify bounties to allow multiple users to separately award bounties to a question.

Now, I know this idea [has been brought up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64768/more-than-one-person-should-be-able-to-offer-a-bounty-for-the-same-question-at-t). I'd like to clarify how this question is different:

1. The referenced question proposes making a bounty 'pool'. I'm proposing making a list of bounties.
2. The accepted answer to the above question was "This idea has issues with awards and it says no in the blog."

Edit: As it seems that this idea has gotten pushback, I've modified the question into a `Discussion` question and would like to know *why* it's a bad idea beyond simply that "The blog says no."

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258136/how-do-i-write-a-good-feature-request

Comment: Not entirely. I'm editing my question for better clarity, but there's no indication as to why this feature won't be implemented.

Comment: just in case this gets closed as a duplicate of the other 9 year old question I put a bounty on that for an up-to-date answer

Comment: See also (and right column): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54315/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61869/282094    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69407/282094

Comment: While all of these are valid, interesting questions that are relevant to the topic at hand, they were also asked long ago, before we had access to a *decade* of user data.

Comment: On Linux, you can use [Pinta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinta_(software)).

Comment: I've got gimp and medibang, too. I just find that mspaint is the fastest way to edit images.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think there shouldn't be any issue implementing N parallel bounties which can work separately from each other. Each would work following the same exact logic as now, and the only major difference would be in the site's layout to show them all together.

I don't believe we have to abide by the wisdom of the users from 2010, a decade ago. In 2020 I think we can have a new, modern discussion about this today.