# Add an expand/collapse button to answer contents

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface

Adding a collapsible region to each answer would ease navigation in questions with many lengthy responses.

The accepted answer should be in the first row and the remaining answers can be sorted by vote, for example.

Implementing it with AJAX could also save a huge amount of server and user bandwidth.

Comment: I don't understand why people down voted my question. They might be too lazy to drop a comment describing the underlying reason.

Comment: Note: [downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) have a different meaning here.  Please don't take offense.  Your question / feature-request is quite reasonable, but the voters simply disagree with your suggestion.

Comment: Also, when you include things like `The accepted answer should be in the first row ...` this isn't specific to your feature request. But it's something that the more experienced users may quickly vote you down for because we already have several methods of sorting answers.

Comment: I despise collapsed/paginated content :(

Comment: @six: but you can expand the collapsed parts by pressing expand-all button. :-)

Comment: @xport: I'd prefer not to click at all to be honest. I'd need some good examples of some questions where collapsed content would make reading it easier.

Comment: With collapsed answers, you have to click on all of them to find out which is really the best. It might look better, but it's not going to work for SE. Nice idea though.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at certain questions with **hundreds** of answers like [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44177) for instance, the answers are displayed in pages.  To rewrite this into an AJAX setup would probably take a significant effort.

My hunch is that this sort of thing will come some day -- when more and more questions have *pages upon pages* of answers -- but probably not for at least another two years...

Now for specific questions or responses like these two:

[Why does dust stick to rotating fan propeller?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1343)

[Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19922)

You could consider suggesting edits to the lengthier responses by, for example, trimming those pictures down and placing them side by side.

Just my $0.02.

Comment: +1 for answering. thanks. I am waiting for others.

Comment: Collapsing 50 answers per page will be useful in the first link you gave above.

Comment: yep No worries.  As I said in my comments, (one now deleted), I'm a nobody, but I thought I'd try to give it my best guess so that you wouldn't feel self-critical..  Ps. This is one of those questions I'd love to [toss in 50 rep to add to your bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2261) (and thereby forfeit my right to get any) because I'd love to see this sort of change to the UI -- but as I said, it'd be a **huge** change...

Comment: This doesn't have to be a major undertaking...just a little CSS to hide things, an HTML button, and a little JavaScript to show/hide a region of interest.