# Is it possible to import comments into a chat room without the link appearing?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, chat

**Question:** *For an answer on a stack exchange site with say 8 comments*, how can I / is it possible to import the comments into a chat room?

**Background:** I was helping with a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/280916) and made several comments before I saw the link to auto-import comments into a chat room.  This was awesome by the way!! Note that the person who asked the question left a link to the chat room in a comment.

I wanted to make a similar chat room [out of this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86502) because I edited an answer which wasn't mine and added a paragraph.  I wanted to chat with the answer's author @JonHopkins to say, 'hey feel free to remove my edit -- just wanted to add my $0.02' -- especially as the stack exchange engines said not to add an additional answer.  HOWEVER, **there was no link to auto-import the comments** -- probably because I hadn't previously left one, but I'm not sure.

So I ask here, Stack Exchange Gurus, could a static link be added to auto-import a series of comments into a chat session?

Comment: Is it possible to _beg_ for this feature?

Comment: Point more people here, to vote. (I just added my vote.)

Comment: @Geo Btw, after the bounty is awarded the bounty note is not visible anywhere, even in `/revisions`. I'm certain of this.

Comment: @Manishearth ok, thx! I'll award this bounty, take a snapshot and open a question addressing this tomorrow (can't award fresh bounty for 24 hours).

Comment: I have created a chat discussion for this question [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/626/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing).

Comment: Forcing comments to migrate to chat being restricted to moderators is fine, but I would really like a way to suggest that we take this to chat now, rather than waiting for the suggestion to pop up.

Comment: Having that possibility early on would have saved a bunch of posts from an overfloating comment queue we had to cleanup later. How often I wished for such a link and it wasn't there! 4 years, is there really no way or will? ;)

Comment: @Izzy Try a bounty again, because the last active state is of 2 years ago, so SE team probably forgot it.

Comment: How about "Let's chat" without having to do with the question? Of course, no direct invite should be made available (Spam alert), rather, we should be able to tag and say "Let's chat", and then choose "would you like to import this to chat?" and choose, with or without. And others hould be able to request to join, if that's not possible already.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288572/162102

Answer (score 41):

So, is there any movement on this? I asked a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107274/take-it-to-chat-before-the-message) that was closed due to being a duplicate. People seem to want this so... will it happen?

Comment: [Same here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108669/feature-request-migrate-comments-to-chat).  This seems to be needed.

Comment: @Richard: That one is request for a moderator tool, which is not quite the same as this one. I would rather have this as available to anyone (maybe limited by a rep limit).

Answer (score 30):

That isn't possible (yet) but it may be a good feature to think about adding in the future.

Comment: OK, the "yet" was 4 years ago – and "the future" is now. Still impossible? Whom to beg, where to nag for it?

Answer (score 13):

This issue has been brought up twice recently, amusingly by mods from the same site:

- [Could moderators be allowed to migrate comments to chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109273/145951)
- [Feature request: Migrate comments to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108669/145951)

I think the use case is a little bit different than this post, but since they keep getting closed as duplicates I will make my case here.

**The feature we are looking for already exists**, it seems to be just a matter of who has access to it. The migration of chat comments already happens if one of the commentors clicks the suggested link to do so. The point [I was trying to suggest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109273/145951) was that a moderator should be able to instigate this action before they scrub too-chatty comments from a post so that commentors that were still going at it could reference the conversation.

Comment: If this is now the canonical place for asking for a moderator tool to move comments to chat (doubt it), here's the original request I made for posterity: [Provide a tool for moderators to migrate comments to chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat)

Comment: @MarkTrapp Actually this answer was in frustration at having had my question closed of a duplicate of something I didn't think it was. Your post seems to be the one that it _should have been_ closed as a duplicate of. That should be the canonical place for this one. (And if I thought they were really duplicates I would VTC this one to yours ;-)

Comment: Technically, this question isn't for moderator tools. It's for users to be able to recognize that a comment conversation will not end quickly and can just say, "OK, everyone who cares, meet me in chat" and have a chat room already set up with previous comments and everything.

Comment: The problem is that the 2 questions you refer to was closed as duplicate of the wrong question. The first moderator related question that your question should really be closed as duplicate of was the [Provide a tool for moderators to migrate comments to chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93444/135505) originally posted by @user149432.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue with an existing (and ever growing) comment thread, where the other participant didn't seem to want to migrate.

One thing you can do, to migrate comments, is to simply create a chat room and post the permalink URLs of each comment (you can get the permalink from right clicking the timestamp of a comment). Posting the permalink generates a quote of the original comment, with a username and timestamp.

You can then comfortably delete or flag any remaining off-topic or obsolete comments.

Nonetheless, I fully support this feature-request. Migrate to chat should be easier and more predictable than it is now.

Answer (score -6):

Copy the comments to a plain text editor, such as notepad, so that the UTF and link information is stripped from them.  Afterwards, copy and paste the contents from the notepad editor into the chat window, and the comments will appear.

They may not be formatted very well, but they won't be links. However, they will be there, in your chat, for reference.

Comment: Not really a solution to the feature-request. Merely a complicated workaround. There is also the things you have to do with adding a link back to the original question/answer where the discussion originated, and also a link on the original comments place to direct people to the chat so the "discussion" is not continued in the comments.

Comment: You can copy and paste the comment links e.g. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing#comment607822_160738) into chat and it will be oneboxed, with formatting and names and everything.