# Take it to chat before the message

Tags: support, comments, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to import comments into a chat room without the link appearing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing)

When you get into an extended dialog with someone in the comments section, a nice suggestion box comes up to tell you to take it to chat. That's all well and good.

Is there a way to take a conversation to chat *before* that box shows up? Sometimes, you can tell that you're about to get into a dialog, and it would be useful to just go, "OK, anyone who want to talk about this, meet me in chat" with a handy link to the chat room in question. If there isn't a way, could we get one?

Comment: It's strange to think that when chat first came out they (sort of) had this feature, but then removed it after a while because nobody used it

Comment: If you can import arbitrary comment threads to chat, it's trivial to import ten of your comments starred by ten different people, and get the "Outspoken" silver badge. (I believe I've seen a thread on Meta before indicating people got the "Talkative" badge this way)