# Feature request: Migrate comments to chat

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to import comments into a chat room without the link appearing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing)

It seems that I run across a lot of comments that are interesting and contain interesting links and comments, but run way past the boundaries of "chat".

I really would like to be able to migrate these comments to chat instead of just deleting them, since their content is valid and interesting (but completely off topic).

Could we add a moderator option to a post to migrate all the comments for that post to chat?

Comment: Isn't that already in place?

Comment: [Very similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing), though that one is not about a moderator tool.

Comment: @PaddedCell *Migrating* comments to chat is not in place.  However, we do have something that directs us to chat *after* we have posted 3+ comments individually (per [Fabian's link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing) and as we have all seen, I'm sure.)  I'd really like to be able to migrate the comments to chat.

Comment: Odd, I could swear Moderators would have the ability to throw comments into chat...

Comment: @PaddedCell That may be possible on the trinity, but I haven't seen it on the network sites.  (If I'm wrong and there's a way, *please* show me how!  I'd love to be wrong about this!)

Comment: @PaddedCell - There's no such feature available to me as a community mod on an SE 2.0 site.

Comment: It's pretty much the same request; who exactly is able to do this is a minor detail.

Comment: @balpha I agree.  How it would happen and who performs the action would be an implementation detail.