# Could moderators be allowed to migrate comments to chat?

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide a tool for moderators to migrate comments to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat)

Over on [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) we're drowning in comments. Posts are constantly spawning discussions and we delete *a lot* of off-topic comments when they start wandering from improving the posts to side topics. The deletion practices have been the subject of [lots of](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/546/30) [complaints](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/602/30) and we had to launch and education campaign to [explain what comments are for](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/614/30).

That helped, but it's still not quite satisfactory. It is still common for comment threads to start out as mini-meta discussions on the quality of a post, but at some point they start chasing theological goose trails.

The links presented to active commentors to migrate to chat are great and a few people have used this well, however the majority of people ignore the warnings and keep right on commenting. **Rather than cause continuous consternation over deletions of ongoing conversations, I propose moderators be presented a tool to create these chat rooms** and auto-migrate the existing comments to a new room. Users ignore the hints to do this and just deleting things is not well received, but being able to force the issue and migrate to chat would allow us to clean up the comments on the site AND allow the users to go on talking.

I realize we *already* have one of the most prolific chat room creation rates per-capita on the network. I don't want to flood the chat system but the alternative is not not having chat rooms, it's constantly having to talk users through actually hitting the link themselves.

Comment: @PaddedCell: **This is not the same feature request!** I'm looking for a moderator only tool here, I actually don't think this is a good idea as a static link for everybody like the other one requests!

Comment: Also I see another C.SE mod did beat me to the request with an [actual duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108669/145951) but his question was closed as a duplicate of the other post which also was invalid. Please consider the moderator tool request separately from a user-feature.

Comment: I think that the feature-request is valid...if it's available for Moderators, High-Reps or all users is just an implementation detail.

Comment: As I said on the other post (and the OP agrees), the requested functonality is identical. The difference is only who has access to it (and if this gets implemented, it certainly makes sense to make it available to moderators).

Comment: @PaddedCell: Since the feature _already_ exists for whoever is doing the commenting and just isn't available to moderators, isn't this whole discussion about implementation details in the first place?

Comment: @balpha: This feature already _is_ implemented and _not_ available to moderators. That's what lead me to this post in the first place.

Comment: I added the real duplicate, which I asked way back on June 1.