# How should long comment threads with important information in them be handled?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, deleted-comments

Apparently, some moderators feel that they have a *duty* to delete long comment threads, *no matter what*. That once the thread is automatically flagged for being unusually active, *it is an indisputable order to delete the comments*.

The moderator in question even said the following in defense of his actions:

> I scanned it, and while there was a good amount of relevant information, the comments section is not the place to put relevant information.

What... the... heck?

If there is "a good amount of relevant information", then that should *not* be deleted outright. Especially not with a mere 9 minutes warning given, which gave the participants of the discussion no chance whatsoever to incorporate this "relevant information" into an answer.

[The meta thread discussing the deletion, and the answer given by the moderator in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119000/33213).

Answer (score 20):

I personally think that long comment threads should be moved to and continue in chat, which is designed to handle more informal discussions like these.

---

**Update:** Since August 2014, moderators now have [the ability to migrate comments to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237983/162705) once for any post (question/answer).

Answer (score 11):

Comments can arise in any number of ways, and I feel that any attempt to formalize what a comment "should be" would be a needless restriction on the unbounded creative potential of the community.

Of course there are comments that don't contribute to the subject matter and that won't be missed, and removing them improves the overall quality of the post and the question as a whole. But that should really be the guiding principle: How can the content on the page be improved, and how can visitors (as well as the productive community) be served better?

I can't speak for other languages, but in a language as complex as C++, hardly anyone can claim to know everything. Many an answer has been written in the best faith, but was significantly improved upon later thanks to a comment. I might claim in earnest that a great part of my understanding of C++ originated in comments.

But the author of the post may not always stick around or be interested in "maintaining" an answer. And why should she? We certainly don't want to load any permanent commitment on any intelligent would-be poster who chances upon our site. If an answer is valuable by itself, then it should be allowed to stand, without the demand for anyone to "continue working" on it -- we're a question-answer site, not an encyclopaedia. But when valuable information is added in a comment, that too should be allowed to stand, no matter the volume of the comments.

[As @Sehe suggests, it *is* an option to have some other member of the community perform editorial work on a post, perhaps incorporating comments into the main post. However, this requires someone who is both competent at the subject, diligent enough to actually *improve* the post without harming or distorting it, and who would actually spend the time on going back to older posts to see if they need working on — in practice this seems to happen very rarely, not surprisingly.]

The visual style of Stack Overflow already does an excellent job at keeping the visual noise coming from comments at a minimum. So if an answer is complete and good, any visitor is entirely welcome to read only the answer itself and move on. If she wants to know more and see other people's take on the matter, the comments are available on demand.

In short, I do not see the necessity for policing all but the crudest and most egregiously unproductive comments. Otherwise, if a comment doesn't mean anything to you, that's fine - just walk on by, and maybe it'll be useful for someone else.

Comment: +1 for some nuanced points and the gist of 'if it's not useful to you, ignore it'. However, I'd like to disagree on the need to 'maintain' answer. It's ok, though, if someone else picks up the slack (which I sometimes do, and it has happened to some of my own answers.) And a big +++1 for 'a great part of my understanding of C++ originated in comment threads'. Absolutely, and I always suggest to mutually delete discussion after incorporating it in my answers.

Comment: @sehe: I think the post says authors have no obligation to maintain an answer, though the community may maintain if it values the answer.

Comment: It's entirely OK for someone else to edit an older answer if the original author is no longer interested in it, and that's a good point. In practice I haven't really seen this happen a lot (or at all), though, and it would certainly require someone who's sufficiently capable to do this in a way that improves the quality of the post and isn't actually harming it. There are many subtleties in the field, and an error in paraphrasing would be worse than just leaving the comment in place. But indeed, this is one solution.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Nah, I'm pretty sure it's my answer to `this` thread.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, I'm not a Stack Overflow user, I'm an [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) user - as such, the culture there is different.

Anyway, here is the tl;dr: Edit edit edit flag edit.

First of all, there is the problem of comments in general - I agree that for long threads, it should (and are generally on Ask Ubuntu) be moved to chat - however, if comments are second-class citizens, chat is a third class that is ignored.

However, that will be ignored for this, and it **doesn't** solve the problem of long comment threads.

As I go through cleanup on Ask Ubuntu, I will often come across lengthy comment threads - and when that happens, I do one of a few things:

- If there is something worth adding to the question, edit the important stuff into the question, then flag [ALL THE COMMENTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w2TF.jpg) for purging with fire from Mordor.
- Flag all the comments as too chatty, if there is nothing of value/they are more than ~3 months old.
- If there is an answer in them, make a community wiki answer and also flesh the "commanswer" out into a real answer.

Comment: "Flag all the comments as too chatty" - FYI, I've had good results with just flagging the question / answer with a custom description that the comments were out of hand or too chatty (instead of submitting a bunch of flags).  +1 from me though, these are good guidelines.

Comment: @jadarnel27 http://cl.ly/DTId - I just do that for one comment and say "Oi, too chatty for all of 'em"

Answer (score 7):

I think relying on the existence of comments is a mistake.  They're de-emphasized exactly because of their unimportance.  Putting important information in them that you don't otherwise have access to isn't a good idea.

I can't comment on the actions of the mod here, but I don't think it's a mod's job to watch a thread and wait for you to retrieve your information before removing the clutter.  I also don't expect a mod to be able to evaluate the importance of a particular comment in every possible topic on the site, or if they could, to carry out such an evaluation.

Comments aren't meant for long back-and-forth discussions either -- it *prevents* people from getting useful information out of them.  Perhaps the conversation was better suited to chat.

The original version of your post here also strikes me as needlessly aggressive, and a little entitled — I don't think you should expect SE to host comment threads on your behalf if they don't meet the community guidelines.

For what it's worth, I will offer bounties on the suggestion [Chris links to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119017/154510) until it's addressed (assuming it is not by the time his expires).

Regarding the below comments: My opinion is formulated under the assumption that SE's community guidelines regarding commenting (that they should not devolve into discussions, in particular) are beneficial to the site, which I strongly believe they are.  Whether comments should be accorded more importance or allowed to grow unchecked is a very different discussion.  Mods (should) enforce the rules as they are, and so that is the appropriate frame of reference for evaluating a mod's behavior.

<sub>I'll also note that several of the comments were edited after I responded to them, and not in a good way. What can you do.</sub>

Comment: You're begging the question.  Your answer assumes comments can be wiped at any time.  OP is taking issue with the fact that comments should not be wiped so cavalierly.

Comment: @AdamRackis I disagree. I think wiping comments like that follows directly from the (designed) unimportance of comments and the community guidelines around them. If the OP is taking issue with the fact that comments are unimportant, that is a *much* larger can of worms.

Comment: This is a false dichotomy.  Comments can continue to be designed to be unimportant, while at the same time moderators can behave more circumspectly on the few occasions when valuable information creeps into a comment chain.

Comment: I believe the OP took issue with the fact that the comments were deleted before the information was moved to the answer, with not enough time (after the warning) to do so.

Comment: @AdamRackis Important things are valued, unimportant things are not. That's the definition, no?  I added to my answer that I don't think it's a mods job to evaluate and be able to evaluate the importance of all possible information on the site.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, that's what my answer addresses....

Comment: Relying on the existence of comments may be a mistake, but we don't live in a perfect world. As long as the comments exist, and as long as the contain relevant information that is not contained in any of the answers, then that is the reality that we, the community and the moderators have to deal with. And the way to deal with it is not by closing your eyes and deleting them.

Comment: I think @jalf is right.  I think your position, and that of SO, are overly narrow and ignore the reality in which we live.  Theory here is contradicting reality, and it's time to update the former.

Comment: @jalf You could just as easily say that as long as the guidelines exist and as long as long comment threads have negative effects, the moderators should clean them up instead of closing their eyes to the problems.

Comment: @AdamRackis In reality, we get bad and off-topic questions, and users want to post them.  By the same logic, we should stop closing them! No, I disagree. The solution to the abuse of comments is not to allow and encourage the abuse by special treatment.

Comment: @Matthew: The question is: *Are they really problematic if on-topic and useful?*

Comment: @MatthewRead: I could, but it would be wrong. Because producing relevant and useful information is what this site is about, and sometimes, that is not possible without some discussion back and forth first. Can you elaborate on what these "negative effects" are? It also sets up a false dichotomy where the only options are "allow comments to spiral out of control unchecked", or "nuke the whole thing from orbit". It completely ignores option (3): move the comments to a more suitable location, (4) edit the info into an answer yourself, or (5) give the users time to do that themselves

Comment: @Xeo Read my third paragraph.  There's more to it than that, but I'm not going to summarize all of the theory around comment threads here, it's not what's at issue.  If you want to post a new discussion on whether long comment threads cause problems, be my guest.

Comment: @MatthewRead: how is it "abuse of comments" to have a on-topic discussion about the correctness of an answer? And I love the "I'm not going to actually explain myself here". If you want to post an answer on this subject, do it properly, and explain this so-called "theory of comment threads".

Comment: @Matthew - you're making arguments based on very questionable premises.  Bad and off topic questions **have no value**.  The mod in question actually admitted that these comments **did** have value.  If the system says that valuable content should be deleted, then the system needs adjusting.  Having the mods auto-export the thread to chat would be one simple way of solving this.

Comment: @AdamRackis Auto-export is a great idea. The system says that important info shouldn't be buried in long comment discussions. I think deleting them without special treatment has value in that it discourages the behavior.  It's like having a hard drive fail -- you're not going to go without a backup again.  There are many hundreds of users who protest the closure of questions, and "bad" is subjective, so I wouldn't say that they have no value.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Did you just suggest making hard drives that fail regularly to encourage people to do regular backups?  That's an unusual stance. :D  I'm not entirely sure I disagree.

Comment: @MooingDuck No analogy is perfect :P

Comment: Btw, entitled? Yes, I guess I do feel entitled. I feel entitled to contribute my knowledge on StackOverflow. And if the moderators get in my way when I am doing that, then I think the moderators are doing it wrong. Because I don't think SO should be a mere playground for the Meta Police, for people who want to be part of a popular "thing", for people who want to be part of the "rule-makers", for people who want to "follow the rules". It was once a site for people asking questions, and for people answering those questions. If there is no longer room for that, then I am out.

Comment: And you are suggesting that arbitrary rules for rules sake should take precedence over actually spreading relevant knowledge.

Comment: @jalf The rules about comments are anything but arbitrary. The rules in general are designed to enable constructive participation.  Just because comments can contain important info doesn't mean that encouraging it is the best way for the site to promote important information.

Comment: @MatthewRead: here we have a situation where the rules *prevented* constructive participation. If the rule is there to "enable" constructive participation, then should constructive participation not take precedence over the rule, if the rule suddenly prevents the same? And no one said anyting about "encouraging" comments. We are talking about what to do when the important information is *already* in the comments. You seem to be discussing a completely different issue.

Comment: @jalf The rules about comments do not prevent the use of chat. Enforcing those rules serves to discourage the abuse of comments, which serves to encourage the appropriate use of features, which serves to further enable the asking and answering of questions and the sharing of information. Collateral damage in the form of a few comments being removed is unavoidable and worth it, IMO.

Comment: @Matthew - you're displaying a disturbing dedication to rules.  We're engineers—we're supposed to be smarter than that.  If the rule isn't working right, then we need to tweak it.  Blindly following rules might be appropriate if we were working on an assembly line with dangerous equipment.  But we're not.  Let's focus on optimizing the rules, not just blindly following them.

Comment: @MatthewRead "Collateral damage in the form of a few comments being removed is unavoidable and worth it, IMO." Except that it is neither of those. As others have stated, there are appropriate redresses that can be taken to ensure both the removal of the comments *and* the preservation of the important information. Not taking those steps is *wrong*, no matter how much doing so may be within the rules. This site exists to provide information; information was *lost*. That damages the site, and *that* is not worth blindly following your interpretation of the rules.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - gush - thank you, sir!

Comment: @AdamRackis As I've said, I believe the rule is working as intended, and I've also stated my support for the move-to-chat feature. Kindly keep your opinions on my mental state to yourself.

Comment: @Matthew - relax.  I never questioned your mental state, just the premise of your argument.  Nothing more.  And I think the rule is working too; it just needs a tweak.

Comment: My premise was never "Rules are rules", it was always "I think this rule works".

Comment: @MatthewRead: Except that this "rule" (which is an interpretation, not an actual rule), when applied in the above circumstance, *destroyed valuable information*. What definition of "works" means that destroying valuable information is a legitimate outcome? The purpose of the site is to *create* valuable information. By destroying it, the purpose of the site has been *subverted*. This is *failure*, not success. What about this use of the rule worked in any way productive to the site?

Comment: @Nicol It's impossible to manage and transform information without losing some of it.  It's also clearly not in the best interest of the site to just promote information at all costs.  The information needs to be organized and accessible in order to be more useful.  Deleting information in comments in order to promote the better presentation of it in answers is a good way to accomplish this IMO.  Otherwise people will never learn and will keep burying it comments.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Except that deleting information in comments does nothing to promote anything. It simply destroys the information. Positive reinforcement is always preferred over negative reinforcement. Again, if the moderator simply moved the data over to a chat log or something, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Nicol I disagree, and you can't expect everyone to share your preferences.  Moving the information to chat doesn't encourage incorporating it into answers either, though as noted I do think it's a good idea and support the feature request.