# Disabling comments on questions

Tags: support, comments, reporting

I asked a question on stack overflow, and one of the commenters got angry or something, so an arguing begun. I wanted to close the comments or banning the user from the question, but there seems to be no possibility to do this. How should I handle the situation?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048775/background-image-opacity-css) the question that has the comment war?

Comment: Seems like you're not entirely innocent.

Comment: @MathiasMüller That is true. But now I just want to finish it.

Comment: The best way to finish it... is to stop. I've cleaned things up there.

Comment: @AttilaHerbert You can flag as obsolete, this has no accusatory tone and simply means the issues discussed in the comments has now been resolved; the question is now clarified. At this point you can also delete your own comments

Comment: @AttilaHerbert And yet, my comment above is perfect applicable. That's the best way to stop it.

Comment: Related (and shameless self plug): [Can we get a comments only lock?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171223/162704)

Comment: @Yannis! Have you **no** shame?!?!? That said, I would like that feature sometimes. Or to have an edit-only lock.

Comment: Does anyone have a screenshot? I wanted to rubberneck!!!

Answer (score 7):

- You can **ignore** the comments and **flag** them for moderator attention.
- If the user keeps harassing you despite this, than it's likely that the moderators will notice that this user is getting a lot of comment flags, and they'll respond accordingly.

It's extremely unlikely that it will get so far as the second step.  Most people won't bother to continue leaving comments if you're not responding.

Answer (score 6):

Flag one of the comments, explain the issue, and a moderator will investigate, most likely deleting all comments, and taking any further actions they deem necessary.  Repeated attempts at re-starting unconstructive comment threads will usually result in a short term lock on the post, preventing commenting.