# It should be “large number” of off-topic comments, not “high amount”

Tags: bug, locked-questions, grammar, locked-answers

See this, one of the notices for why a post is locked (emphasis mine):

> This post has been locked due to the **high amount of off-topic comments** generated. A link to a chat room will be posted in the comments below if the conversation was moved to chat.

This is totally wrong. If it is distinct objects, [number should be used](https://grammarist.com/usage/amount-number/):

> Amount is used in reference to mass nouns (i.e., uncountable nouns such as bravery, water, and charisma). Number is used in reference to count nouns (i.e., countable nouns such as dog, year, and eyeball).

It also should be "large", not "high".

**Can this please be changed to "large number"?** It is disintegrating my pedantic brain :o

Comment: Remember, kids, pedantry pays *maniacal laugh*

Comment: I'll bet you also sort your paper money.

Comment: I'd say you're being nitpicky, but I'm sure you'll just come up with a reason why that's not technically the most fitting term.

Comment: [Related and possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/97232).

Comment: The wording implies that there are so many comments that they are not longer countable.

Comment: Is the post notice you mention still a thing, given all the changes to post notices (and locks, including [the release of a comments-only lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340198/335251)) since your post was made?