# Is the “This Is Fine” Winter Bash hat delivered when you get half-bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, winter-bash, secret-hats, winter-bash-2019

My question is virtually the title. I am asking whether you can still get the “This Is Fine” hat if the person who set up the bounty doesn't manually award it to anyone but instead the system awards half of the bounty to the answer posted during the bounty period with the highest score, does that count against the “This Is Fine” hat?

[image]

The [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%EF%B8%8F-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%EF%B8%8F) doesn't solve my question:

> Answer a bountied question and receive an upvote, but not the bounty. Answer must be posted during the bounty period but not necessarily during Winter Bash. If you answer your own question, receive an upvote, and offer the bounty you win this hat when you award the bounty.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would guess not.

Comment: Heh, I wasn't aware of this hat. Love the irony.

Comment: This hat should be awarded to anyone who has visited meta in the last 60 days but still active participates in one of the SE networks.

Comment: @faintsignal No, are you paying attention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you wouldn't get the "This Is Fine" hat even if the bounty's not manually awarded by the user.

You should not get *any* reputation through the bounty if the hat is to be awarded. Tested on [Please don't refer to 2019 as 'a great year'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340333/357396). Ankit Sharma's answer was chosen by the community. But he didn't get any hat.