# Is there a list of new features?

Tags: support

Is there a list of new software/site features?

Maybe a chronological list of links.

Or are there too many to list, or don't you care to publish them?

I'm thinking of this for example: [A comments only lock!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340198/139866)

If I didn't just happen to be reading Meta, I wouldn't know that new feature existed -- and would I ever discover it?

Maybe there is a list and I don't know that the list exists, nor where.