# Comment lock message is overly broad

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, comment-lock

Since recently there is the ability to [lock only the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340198/361484) to a certain post, which I think is a great addition. The implementation however could use some tweaking I think.

The comment link which usually allows you to open up the entry field for comments is replaced by:

[image: Screenshot of notice that replaces the add comment link on a locked post]

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

I think it would be better to replace this with something like:

"comments disabled due to a comment lock"

By this logic it would also make sense to have a custom message for the other reasons one might be unable to comment, i.e. a community wiki post, a deleted post etc.

Comment: How about *comments disabled*, period? Saying it's because of a comment lock looks a little redundant.

Comment: That would also be a great solution @FrédéricHamidi, but it leaves the question why they were disabled.

Comment: You could add *for reasons of moderation* if you think it is not self-explanatory enough.

Comment: I’m conflicted. It’s a complicated message because of all the slashes but it serves an educational purpose by helping users know about the various cases when commenting is prevented on posts. Comments are allowed on CWs, by the way, they are just prevented on CW locked questions... so it’s the lock preventing comments, not the wiki status.

Comment: The [overall messaging there isn't great](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338598/244695) but SE seems to be OK with that

Comment: "comments disabled because this post is deleted or locked" is how I'd phrase it. Posts in review can be effectively considered locked. Get those slashes up out of there, especially *space*-separated slashes.