# Is "Hot Question Potential" an upvote reason?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, title, hot-questions

I saw a [comment in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182206/why-am-i-so-unfit?rq=1), which has indeed a title that would fit in the Hot-Questions.

> ### Why am I so unfit?
>
> +1 for potential Hot Question title.

But is this a reason to upvote a question? I would say no.

Comment: I'd say it's a *bad* reason to upvote a question, but people are free to vote as they choose, good reason or not.

Comment: @iStimple: one voter is not going to make that difference in any case.

Comment: @iStimple NO I am not saying this!

Comment: @iStimple more views = more potentail upvotes

Answer (score 10):

Sure, it's not a reason to vote *for me*.

But people can vote as they please, and you **cannot even know** if the commenter actually voted up, down, or voted at all. For all you know the commenter is trolling; saying one thing, doing another.

You can counter comment; call the commenter out on the silly reason to vote, perhaps. Or you could flag the comment as 'too chatty'; the comment doesn't [add value for future visitors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237980/140890), really.

But there isn't anything we can do to stop that person to vote on questions for reasons you might disagree with.

Comment: +1 for including **bold**, *italics*, and [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238711/212780)

Comment: @Geobits: comment flagged for getting my hopes up. *Where, oh where is my new upvote?*

Comment: I didn't upvote it just now, but I may be one of the eight who did earlier. You can't know :P

Comment: @Geobits: you do know that torture is not permitted under the Geneva convention, right?

Comment: Luckily I'm no longer a recognized combatant. I'm not sure the Conventions apply to non-government individuals (although I'm sure torture is covered by some federal/state law or another).

Comment: @Geobits: on the battlefield of Stack Exchange, aren't we all combatants? At the very least we are cowboys and gunslingers! We have terms like Fastest Gun of the West, the Unsung Hero, with the occasional Tumbleweed blowing past.

Comment: True, but cowboys are behind the times. On PP&CG alone we have [tank wars](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34538/14215), [jetpack laser battles](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28345/14215), and [aerial dogfights](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35328/14215). Let's just hope the SE government doesn't sign the treaties :D