# When moving comments to chat, can the default message be changed?

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, moderator-tools

Moderators have the ability to move comments on questions and answers to a dedicated chat room. When they elect to do that an auto generated comment is created that says

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.

The word chat is a hyperlink to the new chat room. Moderators can edit or delete this comment, just like any other comment.

Typically, after moving the comments to chat, the moderator deletes/purges many/most/all of the comments. Many users do not like when this happens and the auto generated comment is not that informative. A site that I moderate is developing a FAQ related to moving comments to chat. It would be ideal if we could, on a per site basis, edit the default comment to include a link to the FAQ and be worded in a way that better suits that community.

While the more descriptive comment can obviously be done with a careful cut and paste job, the auto generated link to the new chat room means that there is a chance of user error.

Is it possible to have the default comment text when moving comments to chat be set on a per site basis?

Comment: Related (maybe a dupe, if interpreted broadly?): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272433/162102

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the standard reason could be:

Comments [archived](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372042/why-was-this-beginner-question-deleted#comment618369_372042).

Or with the link to the sites faq or help centre.

Comments [archived](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372042/why-was-this-beginner-question-deleted#comment618369_372042). See [How do comments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Tiny change, but can we not have the word "see" as a hyperlink in the second reason you posted? It looks ugly and new users may not expect that to be 2 separate links. Having the word "see" in black is a clear indicator that those are 2 separate links.