# Is proper attribution given when a moderator edits someone's comment?

Tags: support, comments, edits, attribution, creative-commons

As far as I know according to CC BY-SA 3.0 if someone edits any question/answer of a user then proper attribution is given that someone edited such and such content at say 12 P.M 1 January 2015. The CC BY-SA 3.0 license is for any kind of contribution from any user. I've recently noticed that if a moderator changes the *text* of someone's comment then no proper attribution is given, that is its not mentioned that text is not modified by the OP but by the moderator.

So my question is, isn't it a violation of CC BY-SA 3.0?

Comment: Because comments are only temporary, I'm not sure they are included in this. I'm checking the Data Dump, and if they are not there I guess they are not included.

Comment: @Tim At the bottom of every page this line is written: "_user **contributions** licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required_" The word contribution means any kind of _text_ contributed by the user. The Stack Exchange must provide proper attribution to every contribution of every user.

Comment: My point is that I'm not sure comments count as contributions, in the same way that I'm not sure chat messages do.

Comment: @Tim My point is that _comments_ has to be counted as contribution. It is not something related to the policies of this site. On the chat website there is nothing mentioned about which license is being used there.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but assuming the mods follow [the guidance given by Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238095/158100) are they technically contributing? Let's assume the spelling mistakes are corrected by a spelling-checker at submit, is the spelling-checker contributing?

Comment: My question has nothing to do with shog9's advice. Nor with some spell checker software.

Comment: FYI rene most likely never saw your comment, we need to use `@` to notify other users.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The comment is not for user-rene but for every one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most jurisdictions (and to my knowledge in the US as well), there must be a certain level of originality to the work to be able to claim copyright on it.

This means that purely mechanical works can't be copyrighted, and neither can purely mechanical or very minor changes.
If the changes made by the moderators are very minor or mechanical, then there is nothing for them to copyright and thus also no violation of the CC license if the changes by the moderator aren't attributed.

Comment: What is a mechanical work or mechanical change? how much change is considered minor, e.g. upto 5 character? Could you give me some references which explicitly say that minors changes are allowed on copyright material.

Comment: @user31782: A mechanical work or change is something that involved no human intelligence to create. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality. Where the limit is for a minor change is something that must be ruled by a judge, possibly on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 14):

There are very few cases where mods edit comments, in almost all cases deletion is the better option. And if a mod edits a comment, they typically only remove parts of it or replace offensive terms with less problematic ones. Those kind of edits don't really need any protection by the CC license, I wouldn't count them as a proper contribution.

[From the Creative Commons FAQ:](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/FAQ#What_is_an_adaptation.3F)

> In order for an adaptation to be protected by copyright, most national laws require the creator of the adaptation to add original expression to the pre-existing work.

[The section on when modifications must be indicated:](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/License_Versions#Modifications_and_adaptations_must_be_marked_as_such)

> In the 3.0 suite, the obligation to indicate if modifications have been made applies if they result in the creation of an adaptation (when allowed by the license).

A moderator should only correct small mistakes or remove content from a comment, they should never add anything substantial. For that reason it is extremely unlikely that a moderator edit would meet the threshold of originality to be considered an adaptation of the original CC-licenced comment.

We moderators also know that our edits won't be attributed to us, so if we had a problem with that we could just stop editing comments.

Comment: All very fair, but in principle the OP has a point. If you edit a comment it ends up being solely attributed to him, where it was not what he originally stated. It all gets a big "meh" from me, but the TOS doesn't really seem to separate comments out of contributed content and would most likely therefore require equal treatment.

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because I do not agree with the statement _Those kind of edits don't really need any protection by the CC license._ According to cc by-sa 3.0 SE has to give proper attribution. Also I do not want to know why or when mods edit comments. My question is straight forward, _isn't it a violation of cc by-sa 3.0?_ if no then how?

Comment: @user31782 I added some information from the Creative Commons FAQ to support my point that this kind of insubstantial edit doesn't necessarily have to be attributed.

Comment: Just to note, another case is when the comment is considered valuable and the user asks the moderator to edit the comment. In that case, it's again the user's text, the moderator is just an agent.