# Should comment moderation work differently on meta sites?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, per-site-meta

The [guidelines on moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237978/160917) on main sites are well-established: comments are transient Post-it notes, they are second-class citizens, they can be deleted at any time for a number of reasons, and so on.  However, those guidelines explicitly say "These guidelines are for main Q&A sites (not meta sites).".

Fair enough.  So what about meta sites, especially site-specific meta sites?  Should comment moderation follow the same guidelines?  Or should comment moderation be "looser"?  If it should be looser, what guidelines should be followed on meta sites?

I realize that each site and community might evolve its own culture and expectations regarding comment moderation on its meta site.  But what would be a good default or starting point?  Are there any guidelines or principles that are likely to be appropriate for many/most meta sites?

Comment: That's not really about the tools used for moderating, only about the moderation concept itself, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a matter of common sense. Even on main sites, I'm not a fan of blindly reaping comments. I think the reason we have for purging comments is useful here

> Comments should be purged when they have degraded into pointless
>   bickering and / or noise, and the entire set is unsalvageable.
>   Otherwise, selectively delete comments.

Are these meta comments of use to future users? Are they too minor to be questions on their own? Do they add to the 'corpus' of knowledge for future users or moderators?

In short, they're guidelines and if a comment is useful and wouldn't work out any other way, Its worth leaving IMO

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts!  That quote seems to focus on a special case, though: it's talking about about when to indiscriminately delete all comments under a post.  That's a special case.  I think the more interesting question is about when to selectively delete individual comments.  Any guidelines or principles for that?  Should the criteria be basically the same as for the main site, or are meta sites special in this regard?