# Moderator's view of comment edits is erroneous?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, edits, moderator-tools

Being a Mod, I've edited out a typo in other user's [comment](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/ukrainian-formal-professional-direct-address/1047?noredirect=1#comment2625_1047).

After pressing the pencil icon saying "this comment was edited %d times", I see the following:

[image: comment edit history]

From the display, it looks like I did the Rev. #4, too.

I swear I've edited the comment just once (Rev. #5).

**Is it a bug**?

Comment: I can confirm that rev #4 was created by me (not bytebuster).

Comment: Sidenote: [I wouldn’t use your mod powers to edit out typos from comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238095/255554) (except for obvious typos in links that waste everybody’s time).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, absolutely; before I edited it, I confirmed with the OP that it was, indeed, unintentional typo. And arguably, it was a *bad* typo, a wrong declension ending in a post asked by a non-native speaker who may have remembered a wrong declension.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed this bug too. It kind of irritates me, even though only mods and CMs can see comment revision history - makes it look as though you're putting words in somebody's mouth when you're *not*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the timestamps were also off - the user name and time were taken from the *next* item in the history by mistake.

I've fixed the issues and this will be with you in the next build (after rev 2017.3.16.25440)