# Engagement in chat

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

A recurring pattern I see on posts is that a moderator swoops in and moves comments to a chat.

I find that this mechanism almost never encourages additional discussion, but it is used as a deterrent. Visiting the chat the following day sure enough shows that nobody further engaged in anything and people kept on commenting on the post itself.

I'm sure I'm not the only only one who would like to know how hilarious other people thought my comments were leading up to the relocation to chat.

Additionally, I am never notified of activity in chat rooms that I am in. I also have no idea how to get back into a chat room that I am a part of.

Why are chat rooms such a sequestered and ethereal feature of Stack Exchange?

Comment: *[ethereal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethereal#Adjective)* - *3. Delicate, light and airy.* (may not cover it)

Comment: Perhaps make the title more descriptive?

Comment: Yes, the context switch is severe enough to kill all attention.

Comment: Attitude here is just too negative, sorry. It doesn't look like you're asking for any constructive feedback or support, but only to rant how bad things are. If you can edit this to be less negative and more to the point, it can  be great.

Comment: A proposal to avoid the context switch: *[Should “Move this discussion to chat” be “Add a chat to post”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343054)*

Comment: In any case, this question is most likely a duplicate. It is unlikely this hasn't come up before.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): *[When should moderators move comments to chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237983#237983)*

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Sorry, what should the title be?

Answer (score 0):

Comments are/were/have never been a space for extended discussion. Comments are *ephemeral* and moving a comment thread to chat means it has value (for if it wasn't we'd delete it).

> Additionally, I am never notified of activity in chat rooms that I am in. I also have no idea how to get back into a chat room that I am a part of.

There's always a link under your original chat thread, where it's moved to the comment thread.

> Visiting the chat the following day sure enough shows that nobody further engaged in anything and people kept on commenting on the post itself.

Yeah, that's not right. But people could/should move to chat, and if not, you have your old comment thread archived in chat for reference.

> I'm sure I'm not the only only one who would like to know how hilarious other people thought my comments were leading up to the relocation to chat.

Comments aren't really meant for long lived humour. If you hover over the 'add comments' link it says "Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments".

To paraphrase the Rock... "It doesn't matter how funny your comments were".

We're not a discussion site either - any discussion should lead to a improvement in the post, after which the discussion is no longer needed.

> Why are chat rooms such a sequestered and ethereal feature of Stack Exchange?

Cause chat doth not get enough love :(

Comment: I think it’s funny we keep insisting comments are ephemeral when there are tens of thousands of comments across the network that are 5+ years old still sitting under posts. I’m not criticizing moving comments to chat, which I think is a good thing to do, but this “comments are ephemeral” crutch has got to go. There are reasons for removing discussion from under the posts other than “this 12 year old help page says comments are intended to be temporary”; we should explain those.