# "A year in moderation" posts should include number of edited comments

Tags: feature-request, moderation, statistics

Comments can be [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238095/243091) by moderators. The linked post mentions that changes are logged to prevent abuse, and suggests that moderators should do it "almost never". There is no visible trace of this action in the UI, for non-diamond users.

With the way things are, I believe that the number of edited comments should be included in the statistics listed in "a year in moderation" posts, so that users can get an idea of how frequently it happens. Could it be included?

A secondary advantage of this change would be that users become aware that this is a possible moderator action, since it would be mentioned among the list of things that could happen behind the scenes.

Comment: *There is no visible trace of this action in the UI, for non-diamond users.* There is an indication that the comment is edited, for all users. It doesn't show if the edit was done by a moderator or the OP within the comment edit the 5 minute grace period.

Comment: Also note that the API returns for a comment type whether it was edited: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!--_YsD*WwjU)&site=stackapps&run=true  but unfortunately the Data Explorer doesn't have the edited column in its schema.

Comment: @rene Ok, there is no *clear and unambiguous* trace of this action, then.