# Limits for self promotion, round III

Tags: discussion, moderation, self-promotion

[The chat has come across a case](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5442184#5442184) where one user does something similar to Ira. From the few of his recent answers I looked at, it seems he hasn't done it as badly [as Ira Baxter did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145810/133368). But then he goes out and [actively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12053105/140719) [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316439/140719) [old](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052480/140719) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11879059/140719) ([new](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6757372/140719) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12488603/140719), [too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12363410/140719)) and plugs his products.

Yes, he adds a disclaimer, but still, ***I object***. This site is such an immensely useful resource because so many programmers devoted so much of their valuable time and energy to ***giving away their knowledge for free***. That's what made SO the success it is. Now people like Ira or [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51919/logicnp) come along and ride on the back of that to advertise their commercial products. As I wrote [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145810/limits-for-self-promotion-round-ii#comment417434_145827):
***If only 10% of us did the same, the site's usefulness would drop very quickly.***

Comment: I said if someone wanted to pursue this, I would follow and add my support. To reiterate what I've stated in chat: I don't like this guy. Note also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12053105/868546 is probably the worst, and what really made me dislike his actions. I mean, seriously, a ***two*** year old question?

Comment: I'd like to add: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A56710+url%3A%2aspreadsheetgear%2a as an example of similar I saw recently.

Comment: @Drise: ***four*** year old. `2012 - 2008 = 4`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's worth noting that a fair number of well-respected members do use Stack Overflow in *something* of a professional capacity. And I certainly don't have a problem with folks affiliated with a commercial product answering questions asked *about that product*.

Even when folks are referencing their work in answers to questions on *related* topics, I think you should be a bit tolerant... *As long as the reference aids significantly in **answering the actual question!***

However, the examples you link to fail even this "good, relevant answers" test. Thanks for bringing this to the attention of the moderators.

Comment: [Jerry Coffin has brought up an interesting comparison: In the C++ community, people like PJ Plauger, Pete Becker, Steve Adamczyk, John Spicer, Daveed Vandevoorde, Herb Sutter, and many others enjoy a great reputation — despite the fact that everybody around long enough knows who they work(ed) for. That's because they contributed vast amounts of knowledge to the community _without mentioning their company/product_ all the time. It's their knowledge and contributions that advertises those companies](http://tinyurl.com/94zlj8m).

Answer (score 14):

Round three?  I sense a meme.

I initially deleted them, but then undeleted them because I saw the disclaimers.  I didn't realize that there was a larger, more widespread problem here (it was hard to see in the mods queue, we had a number of spam flags on these answers).

That said, I've looked into this and made sure to get the point across that this isn't acceptable.

I'd consider the bar lowered for tolerance on this kind of behavior, as per the second part of the FAQ on self promotion ("you're probably here for the wrong reason..." yada yada).

Comment: If it takes creating a meme to get rid of spammers, I'll do just that. I hate ads, never browser the web without AdBlock, and then those _§°P($(/"`?_ come along and spam in answers. Really, next thing they'll come up with is flooding blog comments...

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is likely to be wildly unpopular, but how about Stack Exchange allow those who want to advertise products do so by paying a small fee ( by using the existing ability to buy ad space in the right sidebar ) so people who want to see ads can go to a specific place or places to view them? Then advertising links in questions and answers would be banned.

Bottom line is people are violating the *spirit* of SO while arguably still following the letter of the rules. I think it cheapens SO when it's allowed to become a free advertising venue.

Comment: If this would solve the promotion issue, I'd be up for it. Maybe something that could do something like AdWords and return relevant ads to questions/answers, so you wouldn't be looking at a C++ question/answer and get an ad for a C# product.

Comment: You do realize that Stack Exchange has a program where people who want to advertise products do so by paying a small fee to have their ads appear on the right sidebar?  This is mentioned in the same FAQ entry saying that people shouldn't have too much self promotion.

Comment: @MooingDuck My solution goes further in forcing advertisers to do so using the built in methods rather than getting it for free by violating the *spirit* of what SO is about.

Comment: Yea, but his suggestion was to not allow any self promotion at all.

Comment: Tricky line to police and it might lead to more astroturfing.

Comment: @Flexo possibly. But if it to be banned, the offending material can always be flagged for investigation. That would make it easier to police.

Comment: "Small fee"?  Unless ad rates have gone down it was quite expensive for what you got.  I had a SE 1.0 site and pursued promotion on SO, and the rates were easily twice the going CPM rate.

Comment: Some of this exists - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable/104757#104757. I don't see us ever selling *in-post* ads though; the cost in terms of community goodwill would be prohibitive.

Answer (score 4):

From my prospect sbi is with the good stand, we are not here for promotion of our products we have developed yet we are on SO for getting solution of our problems from others and vice versa for others.

SO is popular just for its excellent record of great solutions in it, if we so not restrict these type of activity site soon will be captured by our SEO and BD friends who will use it for promotion promotion and promotion and site will become wage for solution hunters.

Keep in mind suggestion is good but promotion gives it another direction.

Answer (score 2):

It seems people are assuming the guy is following the community rules and is only objectionable in quantity.

But these two answers (just from the top of the first page of [@Flexo's search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A56710+url%3A%2aspreadsheetgear%2a)) *don't* currently have any disclaimer saying the poster is involved with the linked product, as of 2012-09-21T07:12:00Z:

- [Understanding / Modeling formulas from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492692/understanding-modeling-formulas-from-excel/494065#494065)
- [What options do I have for reading Excel files and evaluating formulas in C#, Java and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457696/what-options-do-i-have-for-reading-excel-files-and-evaluating-formulas-in-c-ja/457844#457844)

Answer (score -1):

The site operates on gamification, so it is not true that people are giving away time and knowledge for free (even for Jon Skeet). If they really believe they do, then perhaps they are playing it wrong.

That said, the more irrelevant and deliberate plugs are indeed annoying, I definitely encourage mob behavior to rein in the duds who should not be allowed to go cheap on the paid ads.

Comment: Realistically, the "game" bit only goes so far.

Answer (score -11):

**I applaud it.  Good for him.**

The community has made guidelines as to what is acceptable, and he seems to be following them.

He's wearing his 15 pieces of flair, but you don't seem to be happy yet.

I've found it incredible that one of the founding members of this site can, with a straight face, bring attention to the practice of [digital sharecropping](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/08/are-you-a-digital-sharecropper.html) on his blog, and profit handsomely by developing a platform for people to practice digital sharecropping.  <strike>Not only that, but train them to *actively discourage* even the slightest breaking-out of self-promotion</strike>.

Are you upset with this user, or upset with yourselves that you don't have the gumption to do the same?

Comment: I am upset because it is violating the *spirit* of SO and it cheapens the quality of the site. SO is not intended to be a place for free advertising. BTW, I'm not upset with myself or these users. I don't like the practice.

Comment: @John Though there is a difference in branding yourself through the knowledge you contribute and thereby implicitly branding your "product" (via interest in you and what you have to offer beyond your contributions here) and outright branding your product. I can somewhat see how the latter irks some.

Comment: You are joking, right? I sense a troll in our midst.

Comment: No, not a troll, someone who just sees things differently.  See also: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/578/woohoo-seven-hundred-days-in-beta

Comment: You appear to have somehow interpreted that sharecropping blog post as "don't base your site on user contributions ever", which is pretty obviously not what he meant

Comment: @MichaelMrozek No, I didn't interpret it that way. I interpret the post, taken in the context of others he wrote, as "Don't digital sharecrop ... except on my sites."  It has nothing to do with site owners, but how people direct their creative efforts.

Comment: @John Nobody is forced to use SO. They do so because they get something out of it such as answers to questions or the joy of helping others out. Or the ability to put links to ones product pages in a profile etc.

Comment: @Chimera Jon Skeet!

Comment: I was thinking about upvoting this at first, but I'm not sure what the "digital sharecropping" reference is, and I'm not on board with the tone of the last sentence.

Comment: @Chimera And I do too. But there appears to be a witch hunt going on here because people are mildly disgusted how some people can follow the rules and also promote themselves more than the average SO user. So make the rules more explicit and chase these evil entrepreneurs away. Problem solved?

Comment: @PopularDemand Added the link.

Comment: @John I think the problem is that the rules and perhaps the intended *spirit* of SO are somewhat at odds. I'm in favor of changing the rules so that entrepreneurs are forced to use the existing advertising mechanisms on Stack Exchange. Self promotion or product advertising in answers, IMHO, cheapens the quality of the various Stack Exchange sites. I don't believe Stack Exchange was created as a place for free advertising. And your tone again in saying "evil entrepreneurs" is a bit off putting.

Comment: Thanks for the link. You're being a _tad_ hyperbolic with the "even the slightest breaking-out" bit. Users are welcome to advertise their companies/products/projects in their profiles (website, About Me) and even usernames. Also, I think Jeff would argue that contributing to SO isn't exactly sharecropping because you can build SO's brand and your own brand with the same content. After all, your top posts and total rep show up in Careers, right? On the whole though, interesting point.

Comment: I am sorry I read this waste of time. I certainly won't deign to comment on it.

Comment: @sbi Aside from the fact that you contradicted yourself in your comment, tell us how you really feel? :)

Comment: The strong anti-self promotion sentiment here is certainly not something that Jeff or anyone else has "trained" people to have. It's a genuine impulse that comes *from* the community.

Comment: Hey @Pekka, so nice of you to join the party. :) At least you deigned to comment on the post, and I appreciate that. The training happens all the time here; that's essentially the same thing as coming from the community, I think. I like low-noise as much as the next guy, but if I had a tool that could solve someone's problem, why shouldn't I be able to explain how to do it in an answer to a question here? What would it matter if I gained financially? To me, this anti-self-promotion sentiment looks too much like "I don't have anything to sell, so you can't sell your stuff either."

Comment: @John most people here *do* have something to sell - their expertise. But they consciously choose to give some of it away for free on this site, and you have to understand the skepticism towards others trying to make a buck (and as said, I think this is a genuine sentiment in the community.) And at the end of the day - while I have nothing against self-promotion within certain limits - I believe in one basic rule: if a product is awesome for solving a problem, someone else is going to recommend it over time, from their own experience with it. *That* will then make a good answer.

Comment: If SO is really such an effective vehicle, people will just come up with more elaborate methods for indirect promotion.

Comment: John, this is a decision you have to make for yourself, and folks have been making it for much longer than the Web - or the Internet - have been around. I can hardly fault anyone for **not** wanting to *give away* their time and expertise... But, if that *is* what you decide to do, then you should do so honestly - using the pretext of answering as a cover for advertising is nothing more than an abuse of those who are playing it straight.

Comment: @Shog9 Sure, I enjoy helping people here (for free) as much as anyone who does the same. However, I guess I don't see what is dishonest about (1) answering a question using a product you sell as the solution, and (2) disclosing that you have a financial relationship with that product. These seem to be the rules of engagement, and yet there are still issues because of meaning of intent ascribed beyond the rules. If the answer (as given above) is poor, then downvote it or flag it, but if it's good and helps the person asking the question, what is wrong with it? See what I'm saying?

Comment: @John: see my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147745/limits-for-self-promotion-round-iii/147802#147802) - the primary issue is when these answers *don't actually answer the questions they're attached to.* This is a problem with or without the presence of promotion, but promotion tends to give a bad impression all by itself - so if you're here *mostly* posting links to your own stuff and *mostly* not actually answering anything, then it becomes very, very hard to argue that you're acting in good faith.