# Where can I ask questions on how to set up and run a Maven project?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't know where I can ask my question about setting up and running a Maven project.

I am good at the Bash command line language, but I am absolutely clueless as to how I should go about setting up a simple Maven project in Intellij that no one else seems to have problems with. Nevertheless, everyone has to start somewhere and I need to know knowing where/how to start. I have read dozens of articles about Maven 101, basic usage/setup, packages, troubleshooting, etc. to no avail.

Should I post this question on StackOverflow, AskUbuntu, or where? Also, should I edit the question? Below is a preview of the question.

> After many hours of struggling to set up the [Rapidoid](https://github.com/rapidoid/rapidoid) Maven package in both IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse and trying to get the basic Hello-World example working, I am absolutely stumped and cannot find anywhere online that addressed my issues. Although I have used Java extensively, I have always found a way around using Maven because I can't seem to ever get anything (no matter how simple) to work in Maven. It's not a problem with Bash because I am very comfortable using the command line. As I am a lonely dev with no one else to ask for help with Maven, I am in quite a pickle. Below are some of my hopeless attempts in the console to try to get something (anything!, really) to work. The full log of all the dumb things I tried was too long to post.
>   ! 
>   !
>
> ```
> ! jack@jack-XPS ~/code/java-server/rapidoid $ mvn -v ./examples/hello-world/app.sh 
> ! [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> ! [INFO] Inspecting build with total of 20 modules...
> ! [INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
> ! [INFO]   ... total of 20 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid                                                           [pom]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-test-commons                                              [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-commons                                                   [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-networking                                                [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-sql                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-jpa                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-inject                                                    [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-render                                                    [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-gui                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-server                                               [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-client                                               [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-watch                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-rest                                                      [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-oauth                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integrate                                                 [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-web                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-openapi                                                   [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-quick                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integration-tests                                         [jar]
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid App Plugin                                       [maven-plugin]
> ! Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
> ! Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
> ! Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 kB at 20 kB/s)
> ! Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 30 kB/s)
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Reactor Summary for Rapidoid 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid ........................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-test-commons .............................. SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-commons ................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-networking ................................ SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-sql ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-jpa ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-inject .................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-render .................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-gui ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-server ............................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-client ............................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-watch ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-rest ...................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-oauth ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integrate ................................. SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-web ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-openapi ................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-quick ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integration-tests ......................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid App Plugin ................................ SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Total time:  1.552 s
> ! [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-02T13:20:03-04:00
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'org.rapidoid' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/jack/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> ! [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> ! [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
> ! jack@jack-XPS ~/code/java-server/rapidoid $ mvn runAll
> ! [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> ! [INFO] Inspecting build with total of 20 modules...
> ! [INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
> ! [INFO]   ... total of 20 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid                                                           [pom]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-test-commons                                              [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-commons                                                   [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-networking                                                [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-sql                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-jpa                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-inject                                                    [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-render                                                    [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-gui                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-server                                               [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-client                                               [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-watch                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-rest                                                      [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-oauth                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integrate                                                 [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-web                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-openapi                                                   [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-quick                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integration-tests                                         [jar]
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid App Plugin                                       [maven-plugin]
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] -----------------------< org.rapidoid:rapidoid >------------------------
> ! [INFO] Building Rapidoid 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                  [1/20]
> ! [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Reactor Summary for Rapidoid 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid ........................................... FAILURE [  0.001 s]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-test-commons .............................. SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-commons ................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-networking ................................ SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-sql ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-jpa ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-inject .................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-render .................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-gui ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-server ............................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-client ............................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-watch ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-rest ...................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-oauth ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integrate ................................. SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-web ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-openapi ................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-quick ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integration-tests ......................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid App Plugin ................................ SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Total time:  0.592 s
> ! [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-02T13:20:12-04:00
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "runAll". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> ! [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> ! [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
> ! jack@jack-XPS ~/code/java-server/rapidoid $ mvn clean install
> ! [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> ! [INFO] Inspecting build with total of 20 modules...
> ! [INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
> ! [INFO]   ... total of 20 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid                                                           [pom]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-test-commons                                              [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-commons                                                   [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-networking                                                [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-sql                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-jpa                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-inject                                                    [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-render                                                    [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-gui                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-server                                               [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-client                                               [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-watch                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-rest                                                      [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-oauth                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integrate                                                 [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-web                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-openapi                                                   [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-quick                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integration-tests                                         [jar]
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid App Plugin                                       [maven-plugin]
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] -----------------------< org.rapidoid:rapidoid >------------------------
> ! [INFO] Building Rapidoid 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                  [1/20]
> ! [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ rapidoid ---
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ rapidoid ---
> ! [INFO] Installing /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/pom.xml to /home/jack/.m2/repository/org/rapidoid/rapidoid/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rapidoid-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] -----------------< org.rapidoid:rapidoid-test-commons >-----------------
> ! [INFO] Building rapidoid-test-commons 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT                     [2/20]
> ! [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ rapidoid-test-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Deleting /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/target
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ rapidoid-test-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
> ! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/src/main/resources
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ rapidoid-test-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
> ! [INFO] Compiling 10 source files to /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/target/classes
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ rapidoid-test-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
> ! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/src/test/resources
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rapidoid-test-commons ---
> ! [INFO] No sources to compile
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ rapidoid-test-commons ---
> ! [INFO] No tests to run.
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ rapidoid-test-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Building jar: /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/target/rapidoid-test-commons-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ rapidoid-test-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Installing /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/target/rapidoid-test-commons-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/jack/.m2/repository/org/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rapidoid-test-commons-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> ! [INFO] Installing /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/pom.xml to /home/jack/.m2/repository/org/rapidoid/rapidoid-test-commons/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rapidoid-test-commons-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] -------------------< org.rapidoid:rapidoid-commons >--------------------
> ! [INFO] Building rapidoid-commons 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT                          [3/20]
> ! [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ rapidoid-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Deleting /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-commons/target
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ rapidoid-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
> ! [INFO] Copying 1 resource
> ! [INFO] Copying 12 resources
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ rapidoid-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
> ! [INFO] Compiling 340 source files to /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-commons/target/classes
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ rapidoid-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
> ! [INFO] Copying 17 resources
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rapidoid-commons ---
> ! [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
> ! [INFO] Compiling 63 source files to /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-commons/target/test-classes
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ rapidoid-commons ---
> ! 
> ! -------------------------------------------------------
> !  T E S T S
> ! -------------------------------------------------------
> ! Running custom.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanTest
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> !  @19515@jack-XPS TEST custom.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanTest
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! 13:20:26.605 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.commons.RapidoidInitializer - Starting Rapidoid v6.0.0-SNAPSHOT, built on 2020-04-02 17:20 UTC
> ! 13:20:26.608 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.commons.RapidoidInitializer - System info | os = Linux | java = 1.8.0_232 | process = 19515@jack-XPS | max memory = 910 MB | dir = /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-commons
> ! 13:20:26.646 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.config.ConfigBase - Changing configuration path | from =  | to = ClasspathScanTest
> ! 13:20:26.651 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanner - Scanning classpath | annotated = [] | packages = [] | matching = .*ScanTest
> ! 13:20:26.740 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanner - Finished classpath scan | time = 90ms | searched = 14132 | found = [ClasspathScanTest]
> ! 13:20:26.743 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanner - Scanning classpath | annotated = [] | packages = [custom] | matching = .*Bar
> ! 13:20:26.764 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanner - Finished classpath scan | time = 21ms | searched = 4 | found = [Bar]
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> !  @19515@jack-XPS TEST custom.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanTest
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! 13:20:26.771 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.config.ConfigBase - Changing configuration path | from =  | to = ClasspathScanTest
> ! 13:20:26.773 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanner - Scanning classpath | annotated = [@MyAnnot] | packages = []
> ! 13:20:29.868 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanner - Finished classpath scan | time = 3095ms | searched = 14132 | found = [Foo, Bar]
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> !  @19515@jack-XPS TEST custom.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanTest
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! 13:20:29.872 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.config.ConfigBase - Changing configuration path | from =  | to = ClasspathScanTest
> ! 13:20:29.873 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanner - Scanning classpath | annotated = [] | packages = []
> ! 13:20:29.986 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanner - Finished classpath scan | time = 112ms | searched = 14132 | found = [ConcurrentCacheAtom, CacheFactory, CacheStats, CachedValue, ManageableCache, Cache, CacheAtom, Caching, Cached, CaffeineCache, CacheDSL, WebSetup, ScreenBean, Screen, AbstractTypeSpecificVisitor$1, Proxies, TypeKind, TypeSpecificFactory, AbstractTypeSpecificVisitor, Cls$1, TypeConstants, TypeSpecificVisitor, InterceptorProxy, AbstractTypeSpecificFactory$1, Cls, AbstractTypeSpecificFactory, Values, SimpleValueStore, ValueStore, Value, OrValue, AbstractValue, AbstractDecoratorValue, ToValue, StoredValue, ContextPreservingJobWrapper, PredefinedContextJobWrapper, JobsDelayDSL, JobExecutor, CallbackExecutorJob, JobScheduler, JobsDSL, ManageableExecutor, JobsService, Jobs, InvalidData, Validators, UserInfo, CtxMetadata, With, PersisterProvider, WithContext, Contextual, Ctx, Ctxs, Classes, MediaType, HttpVerb, RapidoidModules, AbstractThreadActivity, RapidoidThreadFactory, RapidoidThread, RapidoidThreadLocals, AbstractLoopThread, LogbackUtil, LogOptions, GlobalCfg, Log, LogHP, LogLevel, RapidoidLog, RapidoidLogFactory, LogStats, Log$1, Log$2, FutureImpl, PromiseImpl, Promise, Callbacks, Future, Futures, Promises, Futures$1, Callback, Insights, PercentMeasure, Metrics, Insightful, InsightsThread, Measure, StatsMeasure, CounterMeasure, AbstractInsightful, JMXMetrics, ResultsImpl, NoResults, NoResults$1, PagingIterator, Results, Range, PageableData...]
> ! Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.488 sec - in custom.rapidoid.scan.ClasspathScanTest
> ! Running org.rapidoid.cache.SimpleCachingTest
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> !  @19515@jack-XPS TEST org.rapidoid.cache.SimpleCachingTest
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! 13:20:34.650 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.util.Msc - avg(ops): 10000000 in 4619 ms (2.2M/sec) | MEM [total=499 MB, used=180 MB, max=910 MB]
> ! CacheStats{requests=20000000, hits=217105, hitRate=0.01085525, misses=19782895, missRate=0.98914475, loads=9891434, errors=0, errorRate=0.0, evictions=9834945, bypassed=0, totalLoadTime=350931663, averageLoadPenalty=35.47834045093967}
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> !  @19515@jack-XPS TEST org.rapidoid.cache.SimpleCachingTest
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! CacheStats{requests=100000, hits=36789, hitRate=0.36789, misses=63211, missRate=0.63211, loads=63211, errors=0, errorRate=0.0, evictions=0, bypassed=0, totalLoadTime=2917549, averageLoadPenalty=46.1557165683188}
> ! CacheStats{requests=200000, hits=100000, hitRate=0.5, misses=100000, missRate=0.5, loads=100000, errors=0, errorRate=0.0, evictions=0, bypassed=0, totalLoadTime=3858741, averageLoadPenalty=38.58741}
> ! CacheStats{requests=300000, hits=200000, hitRate=0.6666666666666666, misses=100000, missRate=0.3333333333333333, loads=100000, errors=0, errorRate=0.0, evictions=0, bypassed=0, totalLoadTime=3858741, averageLoadPenalty=38.58741}
> ! 13:20:39.708 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.util.Msc - avg(ops): 200000000 in 4975 ms (40.2M/sec) | MEM [total=507 MB, used=131 MB, max=910 MB]
> ! CacheStats{requests=200300000, hits=200200000, hitRate=0.9995007488766849, misses=100000, missRate=4.992511233150275E-4, loads=100000, errors=0, errorRate=0.0, evictions=0, bypassed=200000000, totalLoadTime=3858741, averageLoadPenalty=38.58741}
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> !  @19515@jack-XPS TEST org.rapidoid.cache.SimpleCachingTest
> ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! 13:20:39.844 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.util.Msc - avg(changed): 640000 in 123 ms (5.2M/sec) | MEM [total=507 MB, used=161 MB, max=910 MB]
> ! 13:20:40.097 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.util.Msc - avg(invalidated): 640000 in 249 ms (2.6M/sec) | MEM [total=532 MB, used=192 MB, max=910 MB] 
> ! ...
> ! 13:21:30.720 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.env.Environment - No profiles were specified, activating 'default' profile
> ! 13:21:30.720 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.env.Environment - No production/dev/test mode was configured, inferring mode | mode = TEST
> ! 13:21:30.721 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.env.Environment - Initialized environment | mode = TEST | profiles = [default, test]
> ! 13:21:30.727 [main] INFO org.rapidoid.config.ConfigImpl - Loaded configuration | namespace = config | files = [built-in-config.yml, built-in-config-default.yml, built-in-config-test.yml, RoleBasedSecurityTest/config.yaml]
> ! Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.075 sec - in org.rapidoid.security.RoleBasedSecurityTest
> ! 
> ! Results :
> ! 
> ! Failed tests: 
> !   RapidoidInfoTest.testBuiltOn:41->TestCommons.isTrue:179 expected:  but was: 
> ! 
> ! Tests run: 147, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
> ! 
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Reactor Summary for Rapidoid 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.155 s]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-test-commons .............................. SUCCESS [  1.462 s]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-commons ................................... FAILURE [01:10 min]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-networking ................................ SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-sql ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-jpa ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-inject .................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-render .................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-gui ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-server ............................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-client ............................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-watch ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-rest ...................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-oauth ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integrate ................................. SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-web ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-openapi ................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-quick ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integration-tests ......................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid App Plugin ................................ SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Total time:  01:12 min
> ! [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-02T13:21:31-04:00
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project rapidoid-commons: There are test failures.
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] Please refer to /home/jack/code/java-server/rapidoid/rapidoid-commons/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
> ! [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> ! [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> ! [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
> ! [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :rapidoid-commons
> ! jack@jack-XPS ~/code/java-server/rapidoid $ ./examples/hello-world/app.sh 
> ! [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> ! [INFO] Inspecting build with total of 20 modules...
> ! [INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
> ! [INFO]   ... total of 20 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid                                                           [pom]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-test-commons                                              [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-commons                                                   [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-networking                                                [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-sql                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-jpa                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-inject                                                    [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-render                                                    [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-gui                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-server                                               [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-client                                               [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-watch                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-rest                                                      [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-oauth                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integrate                                                 [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-web                                                       [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-openapi                                                   [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-quick                                                     [jar]
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integration-tests                                         [jar]
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid App Plugin                                       [maven-plugin]
> ! Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
> ! Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
> ! Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 kB at 15 kB/s)
> ! Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 22 kB/s)
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Reactor Summary for Rapidoid 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
> ! [INFO] 
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid ........................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-test-commons .............................. SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-commons ................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-networking ................................ SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-sql ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-jpa ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-inject .................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-render .................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-gui ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-server ............................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-http-client ............................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-watch ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-rest ...................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-oauth ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integrate ................................. SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-web ....................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-openapi ................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-quick ..................................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] rapidoid-integration-tests ......................... SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] Rapidoid App Plugin ................................ SKIPPED
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [INFO] Total time:  1.905 s
> ! [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-02T13:21:58-04:00
> ! [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ! [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'org.rapidoid' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/jack/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> ! [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> ! [ERROR] 
> ! [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> ! [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
> ! jack@jack-XPS ~/code/java-server/rapidoid $ cd ./examples/hello-world/
> ! jack@jack-XPS ~/code/java-server/rapidoid/examples/hello-world $ mvn clean package
> !
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I've apparently missed that you are actually asking what site to post this on. I'd *remove* the question preview, as it is actually distracting from your request.

Comment: I'm still not clear as to what actual *subject* your question has. AskUbuntu is not for project questions, there you ask about how to work with the Ubuntu operating system specifically. This sounds like a Stack Overflow question, provided it is not asking for broad guidance and best practices, but rather asks for help with specific set-up problems you encounter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The subject of my question is *how do I do X. Please tell me which concepts I am lacking understanding so that I can research those concepts on my own to solve my problem or refer me to a how-to guide.*

Comment: That's not going to be on topic on any site, that's simply way too broad, sorry.

Comment: You can ask questions about Maven on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven), subject to their topicality rules. You could try posting the Helloworld program and see if you can get anyone to a chat room.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I ask the community to help me on a project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264345/where-can-i-ask-the-community-to-help-me-on-a-project)

Comment: @gnat Thank you for your suggestion. Although it does seem awfully similar to my question, my question is much more primitive and simpler. I'm good at Java and I don't require the help of a team of programmers to create my project. Rather, all I need is a push in the right direction for how I run the Rapidoid Maven package. None of the content I have found online about Maven packages has been helpful for dealing with Rapidoid. Once I figure out Maven for Rapidoid, I'll be good to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @Rob Many thanks but none of those sites really seem to fit my question very well. I have to find somewhere to get my question answered because I have no idea how to answer the question myself.

Comment: @JackGiffin: if none of those sites suit your question then there are no sites left on the Stack Exchange network of sites, sorry. You'll have to find somewhere else altogether and we can't help you with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a tutorial and that is off-topic across all SE sites. It is way too broad to be answerable in a few paragraphs.

By itself the individual topics like InteliJ and maven are on-topic on Stack Overflow and/or [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) depending on context.

Your best approach is to make a start yourself and then search and/or ask for the single step you're stuck on.

Alternatively you might try a chatroom but I don't know if there is one that covers your topic or if they are open for tutoring.

Other venues like reddit, Quora or Medium might be better suited to find a tutorial.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have already made a start myself, spent many hours searching for everything I could find that might pertain to my topic, and I am simply stuck with no idea about what to do. I am not necessarily requesting a take-my-hand tutorial, rather all I want is somewhere I can start my journey to figure out how in the world to set up Rapidoid (and other Maven packages like it). None of the Maven articles I have found thus far have been applicable to my particular set of circumstances