# Is it right to recommend a book in an answer?

Tags: discussion, new-users, behavior, books

I have recently written an answer to a question on one of *Stack Exchange*'s sites. In my answer I included a link to a chapter of a book to add more information about the point I was discussing. Between two parentheses I said that this is a link to a chapter from a given book, and recommended the OP to read it.

So, is it right to recommend a book in an answer? Or should I remove this recommendation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as it is not the only thing in your answer and if without the link the answer still has value I see no issue.

I do assume you're not the author of the book or anyway affiliated with it so you would benefit from sharing that link. In that case you should at least reveal your affiliation clearly in your answer to be not considered as spam. And that link shouldn't subsequently be in every answer you post. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182237/158100) from [Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/159251/josh-caswell) for one example  of how to do that right.

Make sure to check the Help Center and meta of the site your posting on as they might have different rules or more strict citation requirements.

Comment: Perhaps tangential, but for examples of the right way (I think) to link your own book: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182237/