# Are answers that contain advertisements allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam, self-promotion

So I just found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-to-manually-send-http-post-requests-from-firefox-or-chrome-browser) in which the accepted answer is only about an advertisement to an app that solves the problem. No offense to anyone, but isn't it too subjective? If the problem can't be solved without app, in my opinion, they should've just say something like:

> Sorry, this problem cannot be solved without an extension or external app.

In my opinion, advertising in an answer is against the antitrust law, because accepted answers are always on top AND there is only one seat for an accepted answer.

Why wasn't this answer moderated?

Comment: The answer includes that they are affiliated with that product. The answer does answer the question. This is within what is allowed under the rules of promotion in answers.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/what-signifies-good-self-promotion-or-self-promotion-part-infinity

Comment: But doesn't it against the antitrust law ? It feels like the accepted answer monopoly the advertising , because accepted answer is always on top and there is only one accepted answer .

Comment: Also, see [this Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for more info.

Comment: I have no idea what antitrust law you talk about. And that the monopoly for being the top answer is not a problem caused by that specific answerer. Their tool suggestion happened to have helped the OP most.

Comment: Advertising yourself on the Internet does not violate any law. Advertising yourself in an answer on Stack Exchange does not violate Stack Exchange's Terms of Service **if you disclose your affilation and your product really does solve the problem stated in the question**. So everything seems to be fine in this case.

Comment: And if I saw a comment like "*Sorry , this problem cannot be solved without extension or external app.*", I'd still ask for the solution, advertising or not.  As long as they follow the rules regarding advertising.

Comment: “In my opinion, advertising in an answer is against the antitrust law, because accepted answers are always on top AND there is only one seat for an accepted answer.” - This absolutely isn’t the case.

Comment: Based on this wrong logic, most answers by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61413445)) should also be considered spam and deleted, since he wrote the compilers and is affiliated with Microsoft.

Comment: Don't feel sorry for what you asked, everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 19):

> In my opinion, advertising in accepted answer is against the antitrust law, because accepted answer is always on top AND there is only one seat for accepted answer.

[That word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competition_law)  it does not mean what you think it means!

> Sorry, this problem cannot be solved without an extension or external app.

Is a partial answer... it doesn't in any way solve the question poster's issue.

So let’s break down the post

- The OP clearly stated that the tool is his, so there's proper, and necessary disclosure.
- The OP *could* talk about how one would use his tool to solve the problem, which would probably add value, and help others decide if it's right for their needs. It's a minus, but not entirely intuitive.
- The OP clearly had interaction on the site *outside* talking about/suggesting the tool

Just because someone recommends a tool that they wrote or sell doesn't automatically make it spam.