# Where to draw the line at "show me the code" questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I asked a question on StackOverflow which a user is claiming it's a "show me the code" question and isn't acceptable. I don't agree because of the scope of the task. I'm asking for a Delphi wrapper for a large popular third-party API (which in fact StackOverflow has an explicit tag for) called Mandrill. I cannot find a wrapper for it, so I'm asking if anyone else knows of one to spare me the headache of doing it myself, which is a major, major task.

[Is there a JSON or XML wrapper for Mandrill in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373893/is-there-a-json-or-xml-wrapper-for-mandrill-in-delphi)

Would this be considered an inappropriate question?

Comment: closely related: [Should there be a place to ask about programming libraries and technologies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164400)

Comment: I just deleted the question linked due to an overreaction of a user.

Comment: @JerryDodge to answer one of your early comments in the linked question before you deleted it, the presence of questions that are not closed are not proof that similar questions are acceptable but are usually either (1) it has not been found to be closed and/or (2) it was asked when such questions were considered acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree that this is a "show me the code" question, but I do agree that it is inappropriate<sup>1</sup>.  Questions that ask "is there an library for x" are generally considered off-topic on most/all Stack Exchange sites, including Stack Overflow, as they are classified as "shopping list" questions.

The simple fact is these types of questions are rarely constructive.  Typically they turn out to be questions that do not have a correct answer and just are nothing more than a list of links that provide nothing more than "Foo is the best Bar", or "The best bar is actually Blah", but without any real data to support the statements.

For more information see [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

<sup>1 - *inappropriate* is your words not mine.  Not constructive would be how I would best phrase it.</sup>

Comment: That is a good point, and I did think of that when typing it, I made sure to get right to the point on what I need.

Comment: @JerryDodge not sure if you'll be able to do it on your question, but generally the way to get around this is to simply approach this as "How do I accomplish X with Delphi" and hoping people recommend a specific library to solve your problem.  The trick is to invite a real answer rather than a list of links.

Comment: Oh I've been there, and it's been much worse, leading to "You want us to write your code for you?"

Answer (score 1):

These kind of questions are ok if they're very specific, so that you don't get a list of answers.  I didn't get to see the question before it was deleted, but based on the title I'd say that it is specific enough to be ok.