# Where do I ask questions on recommending resources for a specific coding project?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where do I ask questions that ask for a general direction regarding coding?

I'm about to start a new project that involves a lot of different resources that I am not yet experienced with.(probably webGL and canvas)

I'm currently at the research stage. 
I've got my guidelines set up, know what my project needs to do and how it should function.

My next step would be to define the different techniques that would be required for my specific project. And after that, learning these specific techniques.

Is there any stackexchange site that gives suggestions in the research stage of a project? To help form a plan of attack on a project, so to speak.

Comment: see also: [Should there be a place to ask about programming libraries and technologies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164400/should-there-be-a-place-to-ask-about-programming-libraries-and-technologies)

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid that this is all too broad to be asked anywhere within the SE network.

Your question seems to be very localized to your situation and the answers would only be beneficial to you and not so much for future visitors.

Beyond that answers would require a lot more than just a few paragraphs.

Your only chance is to bring it down to a single specific topic. If narrowed down enough you might find similar questions on [programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) but that community is very strict on what can fly on their site. If you plan on asking a narrow scoped question there check their [meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) first. Expect similar rules to be true for [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/).

An other option might be a chatroom but not all rooms are open for these kind of broad discussions.