# Is there any chat feature on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

In [one of my earlier posts](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48525/why-does-cv-yield-lower-score), an user initiated a private discussion for understanding my concern better. (There is a chat window on the 5th comment)

Which badge is required for that?

Comment: Added reference link to my post.

Comment: Mentioned in the Miscellaneous section of the answer to the FAQ [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question in the title: yes, there is a chat feature, which you can reach via the 'hamburger menu' in the top bar:

[image]

What you're talking about is (semi-)automatic conversion of comments to a chatroom.
There is no badge or reputation level required for this; the option will appear [*automatically* once a certain number of comments have been posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwzh5.png) and one of the users wants to post another comment.

> If you and another user post at least four pairs of back-and-forth comments to each other, the system will prompt you to avoid extended discussion in comments and will give you an option to continue the discussion in chat.

It is [not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96247/295232) to do this 'at will', except for ♦ moderators.