# How should one enthusiastically make a feature request?

Tags: discussion, bounties

**When making feature requests, do the "Stack Overflow Gods" perceive a bounty on a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as a means to enthusiastically make a request?**

Three out of four of the [current bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) are for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).  I realize that offering a bounty implicitly increases the visibility of a request, which may or may not attract increased voting.

Disclaimer: My question is partially motivated by a desire to see [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/contribute-to-bounty) implemented.  While the request already had fairly substantial visibility, I believe that over the course of the bounty *only four more users voted.*  Is there a certain voting threshold for feature consideration (for which offering a bounty would help a request attain)?

Finally, I'm also very interested in the responses to this question because, [having offered a bounty here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/contribute-to-bounty) and not received what I deemed to be suitable additional answers, I was unsure how to award the bounty.  Sheepishly, had someone provided an answer, 'Yes, this feature should be implemented', I would've wanted to award it the bounty (*and then quickly felt compelled to flag it as not-an-answer*).

Comment: It's not so much a question of showing enthusiasm for the proposal, or even garnering lots of votes for a proposal. The best way to get something implemented quickly is to demonstrate how it will make the site better for a large group of people. The best way to get something implemented over the long run is to demonstrate how it will make the site better for a small group of people. The common numerator here is demonstrating how it will make the site better.

Comment: Enthusiastically? Waffles, unicorns, and freehand circles obviously. See more information [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only canonical answer will be from the "Stack Overflow Gods" (aka devs), but were I one, I wouldn't assign much weight to bounties. I'd care more about votes, proxy for general desire for that feature among SO's users.

Meta sites use features from the parent sites (votes, bounties, etc.), and that's cool, but they sometimes take on different meanings, as anyone who's [complained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting) [about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97130/add-mandatory-reason-for-downvote) [downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95692/see-who-down-voted) on MSO can attest.

Comment: +1 *Man* am I tired of people who come here to complain about downvoting.