# Feature idea: Bounty Pooling

Tags: feature-request, bounties

(these assumptions are based on StackOverflow.com)

Currently, a bounty may be placed on questions, if the question is (a) two days old and (b) some member has earned the bounty-privilege. After someone set a bounty on a question, it is not possible to increase a bounty for the questioning user.

```
Example:
User A asks a question. User B has a similar problem and adds a +50 bounty.
Now, User A would like to set an own bounty of +200, as the question has
become very important for him, but can't, as a bounty has already been set.
```

So, the idea is very simple: Allow the adding of bounties by different users or **bounty pooling**. If there are several users, who'd like a solution for a question, they can increase the already given bounty by an own bounty.

```
Example (with bounty pooling):
User A would like to make the question a +200 bounty question. As User B
already added a +50 bounty, he stocks up the bounty by adding a +150 Bounty
himself. User C also has the same problem and stocks up the bounty by another
+100, making it a high-value bounty of 300 reputation in total.
```

The bounties should be listed with the user below the question, so that the bounty-givers may be identified. By adding a bounty, the bounty-giver may give an own bounty deadline. The system would perform the regular process at the bounties deadline (give to solution or the answer with the most up-votes).

Comment: Would there be a maximum? I'm not a fan of a question having a 10000 rep bounty because it's popular

Comment: as it says on the [Bounty Page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), only one bounty may be open at any time. I do not intend to change that.

Comment: I don't understand this then. The bounties should be listed separately and have separate deadlines, but there isn't more than one bounty open at a time?

Comment: ah sorry, did not understand your comment correctly. There of course may be a cap either on the bounty itself (not more than +1000 in total) or in the number of bounties (not more than 5 at a time).

Comment: I deleted my answer because I reread your question.  I think I had the lack of a cap stuck in my head.  I do like this.

Comment: Please note that this has [been discussed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/contribute-to-bounty)