# Can we get the ability to boost bounties?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties

In my opinion, [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/389767/274742) is a prime example of when bounty should be awarded. With that in mind, the OP of the question it answers has an open bounty of 100 reputation to reward the existing answer:

[image: Screenshot of the open bounty.]

I also find the answer exemplary and worthy of more than just 100 reputation points. However, I currently have to wait until after the OP awards their open bounty to start a bounty of my own, and then, I have to wait 48 hours to award that bounty.

It would be nice if I could simply boost (by offering my own reputation points) the existing bounty being offered (or even perhaps boost an already awarded bounty).

---

Can we get a "boost" feature for open bounties, and, if possible, already awarded bounties, that functions like offering a new bounty, but without the wait times?

Comment: The purpose of bounties is to attract attention, potentially for more and better answers. Skipping the process circumvents the reason they are there.

Comment: In other words, you're asking for the ***reward an existing answer*** option of the bounty system to be awarded immediately?

Comment: Very great points that require clarity in my post, I'll update to answer them in the question body for future readers.

Comment: Yeah, I like this idea.  I've seen a few bounties on some questions - e.g., questions from the Community VP - where I'd like to give additional points to an answer without waiting or paying 50-100 extra.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contribute to bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/contribute-to-bounty) <- the linked list there also has a number of similar FR's

Comment: This seems risky. The person who originally offered a bounty doesn’t have to reward the answer they said they would, or an existing answer, or any answer at all.

Comment: @Laurel another reason why you could "boost" an already awarded bounty.  Although at that point you could just offer another, I guess...

Comment: If your purpose is inflating the popularity of the answer, it would be in your best interest to offer a new bounty once the current one expires and let it run the full 7 days. Otherwise, you're effectively paying for an ad, and asking the website/app to not run it (while still paying full price)

Comment: @KevinB the duplicate you proposed is, in-fact, asking for the equivalent, so I went ahead and added my flag vote too.

Comment: Well, if it's a great answer, why wouldn't someone want it to stay visible in the bountied questions for as long as possible? Wouldn't it make more sense to want to be notified when that bounty ends so you can give it another week of visibility? If we follow a question, do we get notified when a bounty is awarded? I do think the "reward existing answer"bounties are a bit weird because they feature the question instead of the answer, so maybe the answer is a different solution altogether.