# Allow extending bounties by topping them up (within limits)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

One problem with bounties that has turned me off using them is that if you start one, you will have an answer selected and you may not get any good ones. I can understand the bounty having to end to stop gaming the system but maybe we need some flexibility here?

Perhaps we should allow the OP to pay in extra to extend it another week, a few days or whatever. This should only go on for so long. Maybe a month total? Arguably this extra rep added shouldn't increase the bounty either.

Maybe the amount to extend it is also a function of the size of bounty?

Comment: I don't think a question that hasn't been answered in a week is likely to get a good answer in a month.

Comment: @xmm0, that's arguable. You could be looking for an answer in pure CSS. After a week passes with no good answers, you go to plan B: add Javascript tags, which exposes the question to a new audience.

Comment: @animuson Jeff wrongly marked this as completed, can you please remove the [tag:status-completed] tag please? The request here was never done.

Answer (score 7):

Totally agree. I am now willing to put a bounty on a question I asked, and requires some skills, so the bounty should be high. The question is complex, and unlikely to attract a lot of contributes. Together with the summer period, I am almost guaranteed to invest maybe 300 reps with poor or no perspective of an effective return. The bounty system is a very good idea, but as it stands, it definitely has flaws.

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

This is effectively completed, because

- bounty system is no longer tied to accepting an answer in any way
- you can issue multiple bounties on your question if necessary

possibly related:
[How about making it possible to set up bounty on someone else's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/how-about-making-it-possible-to-set-up-bounty-on-someone-elses-question)

Comment: No, the request in the question was not done. This is something totally different.