# Not happy with answers on bounty question

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, specific-question, bounties

I've asked [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775532/css-grid-system-for-forms-multi-column) and set up a 150 bounty but I'm still not happy with the answers provided, is there any way to extend the bounty, maybe adding some extra points on top of the bounty?

Comment: Just use a table, man.

Comment: Not yet implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/allow-extending-bounties-by-topping-them-up-within-limits

Comment: Tables solve so many of the problems that CSS creates in order to avoid using tables. This circle makes me feel so very warm and fuzzy inside.

Comment: @Gargamel: I've tried (check the comment on my question) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @eyze: Try harder, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an extremely subjective question, though -- what's the "correct" answer? The one that most satisfies your internal sense of aesthetics?

I'd also note that you have quite a few answers, which is the point of a bounty.

edit: this is now possible.
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Comment: But he's not complaining that the bounty didn't get him answers...he's saying he'd like to add to it, and get more.

Comment: This is not about my "internal sense of aesthetics", it's about a specific CSS problem that so far no one seems to have a good solution for it.

Comment: "Good solution" is subjective.  Apparently lots of people think they already have a perfectly good solution that you find fault with.

Answer (score 7):

A bounty is a *contract*.

Your part of the contract is that after the set period of time you provide points to award for the *best* answer, where "best" is defined as either the answer you select or the highest-voted answer if you select none.

The community's part of the contract is to provide your question with extra *attention*.  Not a good answer.  Not even any answers at all necessarily.  The only thing promised to you is that your question will receive additional attention.  It seems like that's happened here, contract fulfilled.

Comment: You're right obviously, but what I'm looking for is a *good* answer and it's a shame that I can extend both the time period and the points offered by the bounty, that way the accepted answer will probably not be a good answer at all. Kinda sucks...

Comment: To limit the opportunity for letting a bounty question persist endlessly, perhaps there could be a "double the bounty" option that doubles the bounty but only extends the question for another 7 days?  You should add a "feature-request" tag to your question if you want it considered as an enhancement.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't that be unfair to the more highly voted answers on the question as it exists?  They know that even if you don't select an answer, they'll get at least a partial bounty award for the highest-voted answer.

If you're up for awarding more points for a better answer, why not just ask a second bounty question with a focus on the points you feel were overlooked in the existing answers?

Comment: Yeah, but it's also unfair that none of the answers provide me with a solution to my problem. I'll probably open up a second question though. =\

Comment: @eyze: I don't see how that's "unfair."  The system does not guarantee you good answers.  Indeed, there is no way to guarantee that.  The whole point of the bounty system is to guarantee people who answer well will receive some kind of reward, in the *hopes* that such a guarantee will fetch good answers.  If you don't get the answers you are looking for, it's unfortunate, it's perhaps inconvenient, but it's hardly unfair, any more than buying a lottery ticket that doesn't win is unfair.