# Extend bounty for unanswered question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow extending bounties by topping them up (within limits)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/allow-extending-bounties-by-topping-them-up-within-limits)

So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114085/how-to-distinguish-identify-users-with-openid-without-requesting-sreg-fields) and it looks like no one has an answer for it. I put a bounty on it, and *still* no takers.

I know that [I can't get that rep back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55155/what-happens-with-un-answered-bounty-questions), but if there's *no* answer by the time a bounty is over, I think the OP should have a mechanism to extend the bounty... even increase it. Having give up X amount of reputation points to find an answer and get *none* (not even bad answers!) may be fair/reasonable, but it also kind of sucks :P

Comment: The concept of bounty extension was proposed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/allow-extending-bounties-by-topping-them-up-within-limits, so this is a duplicate. Think of it like a parking meter - the rep you spent is only good for 1 week of featured status.

Comment: @Grace Note - I disagree; I saw that question, and it states "you may not get any good ones" - my question is scoped exclusively to unanswered questions; not those with answers the OP doesn't like.

Comment: so you want a free extension for a question whose bounty expires with no answers?  the new bounty system already provides a general "mechanism to extend the bounty", so without more specifics this looks like a duplicate of [grace note's link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/allow-extending-bounties-by-topping-them-up-within-limits).

Comment: Indeed, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment on this question, think about "paying" a certain amount of rep for a week of extra exposure.

The new bounty system allows you to set up another bounty when the first one expires, so you can continue to "pay" for exposure for as long as you want.

Comment: This is a good point; I wasn't thinking of the bounty as a price for increased exposure.

Comment: @Jon - he's already paid for the exposure. Why should he have to pay again?