# I would like to assign bounty for a question asked by another person

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about making it possible to set up bounty on someone else’s question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/how-about-making-it-possible-to-set-up-bounty-on-someone-elses-question)

I would like to have a feature that will allow me to assign a bounty to an old question (asked by someone else long time ago) and reanimate the discussion in this way.

Today I found on SO question asked a few weeks ago. Of course I can ask a new question with slightly changed definition, but this will lead to lot of duplicated questions. I suppose we need to encourage adding more information to existing questions if they are clearly formulated, rather then creating new ones. There should be a way to attract attention of SO community to the question that seems to be important.

Comment: This has been discussed before...*searches*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/how-about-making-it-possible-to-set-up-bounty-on-someone-elses-question duplicate

Answer (score 2):

[Simpsons did it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/how-about-making-it-possible-to-set-up-bounty-on-someone-elses-question).

Comment: To great of a dupe line to not +1. Even though TXI handedly beat you.

Comment: Ha, thanks.  That saying always comes to mind when dupes are posted.