# Is text in a gravatar frowned upon?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, advertising, gravatar

I've just updated my gravatar to reflect the logo for my new Stack Exchange site (the cache hasn't updated yet). I don't see anywhere that there are rules for what is allowed in the gravatar, but I don't want to put anyone's nose out of joint. It doesn't have anything too blatant in it, just the domain of my site (se my profile if you're interested).

If there are guidelines that I've missed can someone point me to them please?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but +1 for making a Stack Exchange for movies.

Comment: thanks Chris, feel free to go and post there

Comment: Make sure you logout of Gravatar.com

Comment: i ctrl+f5 refreshed in firefox and that brought up the new gravatar

Comment: yes thanks Brad, I saw the discussion on staying logged in. Was expecting it to take a little while though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The domain of your site should be fine.  You could even change your username to promote your site if you wanted to.  Your gravatar and username act as your signature on every post you make, so it's really up to you what you want these to say.  As long as you don't use anything blatantly offensive, like swearing or, oh... I don't know... an image of Jesus flipping the bird, you should have no problems.

Comment: Stop giving people photoshop ideas!

Comment: ...never mind. Someone already did it anyway: http://img.visualizeus.com/thumbs/08/11/02/bird,finger,hate,jesus,middle,finger-05ab79dc6b058216e2e969d471e4d34c_h.jpg

Comment: @gnovice: Someone on SO was already asked to stop using that as their gravatar. :)

Comment: @Bill: Wow, ballsy! I guess it's not really that surprising though. ;)

Comment: @gnovice: okay clicking that link just brought up a warning from my company's proxy: "this page blocked.  forbidden category: pornography."  Hopefully I won't get fired because of that. :)

Comment: @Kip: "Pornography"?! Your company has some funny standards. ;) It wasn't hard to find... just google "Jesus middle finger" and you get a bunch.

Comment: FYI, ​​​​​​etc.

Comment: +1 for changing one's username to promote one's site ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Why would text in the gravatar be frowned upon? I've seen other people who have had text in their gravatar and never seen any grief from it.

Comment: I thought maybe because it is an advert for my site it would be frowned upon.

Comment: I personally wouldn't waste a downvote on someone who was using a site logo or some such as their gravatar. I would only look down on it if you spent in inordinate amount of time hawking your site at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

If [ClickUpvote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49153/click-upvote)'s gravatar ([image]) is OK, then I don't see why this would be frowned upon.

Comment: But Click Upvote's a troll, so yeah.

Answer (score -1):

No, but you can set the family-friendly level with gravatar to limit things.  I'm not sure for SE sites if you work directly with gravatar, or if Fog Creek does that.

Comment: The SE sites are apparently all set at PG: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/what-is-the-max-allowed-rating-for-gravatars/1439#1439