# Are advertisements allowed within avatars?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is text in a gravatar frowned upon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25696/is-text-in-a-gravatar-frowned-upon)

What is Stack Exchange's policy on avatars?

My avatar on SE sites is automatically picked up from [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/). My gravatar was a picture containing my website's address

Is this allowed?  I'd be surprised if no one at Stack Exchange has seen it already, but I just want to be 100% sure.  The last thing I want to do is invest a whole lot of energy into increasing my reputation only to be banned for a violation of the terms and conditions.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem at all. On a personal level, I find it a bit too much in your face the way it currently is. Although I would probably eventually visit the site, so I guess mission accomplished :)

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello: Well, it _is_ supposed to be "loud."

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello My concern about it being "in your face" is the reason I asked the question. I figured some people might take offence and complain to StackExchange. I see someone edited my question to say "advertisements" :-) Not sure I agree that it's an advertisement since there's no call to action, coercion or attempt to persuade.

Comment: Yeah. I think the bottom line is, it's not viewed officially as a problem - whatever you do inside the boundaries of your gravatar, is yours to decide as long as you don't make it say anything overly egregious like `F*** OFF` or something. Re taking offense, on a site as big and diverse as this one, you can't do anything without *somebody* taking offense, so that can't be the only measure :)

Comment: @Pekka: I take offense to your suggestion that we're hyper-sensitive.

Comment: All this discussion about your avatar motivated me to visit your website...but I don't see anything. Rather disappointing...

Comment: @sarnold I take offense to your taking offense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gravatar is one of the pieces of information on Stack Exchange that's *explicitly* tied to you as a person, so I believe this is fine.  (There are exceptions, of course, such as particularly vulgar or offensive content.  Though, [as @animuson points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123864/148400), that's handled more by Gravatar than Stack Exchange.)

Your profile, to include your avatar, are where you are supposed to put information about yourself and your own interests.  This separates such information cleanly from the content you provide.  Just remember to keep that distinction between the content and the person providing the content.  Don't sign questions or answers, etc.

If you want to provide context to the avatar so people know what it's about, I would recommend mentioning it in your "about" text on your profile.  Your affiliation with the website, what can be found there, etc.

Comment: This is correct, I've seen "official" posts stating as much.  Avatars, usernames, and profile content can be explicitly promotional.  As for animuson's answer though, I doubt SE would sit by if a user was changing their gravatar to something offensive every time the old one got flagged; suspension would probably result.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in doing it, as you have even a profile field for this purpose. I doubt someone would even thing about this. I think you can feel free to have it there.

Usernames with such an adress are legal here on Stack Exchange, too

Comment: Are you ... er, [totally controlled by Selena Gomez?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCLQO4RUgJw)

Comment: @Won't: No, I'm not :), I just like Selena & their songs

Comment: No, no no.  In fact, excuse me while I edit that out.  It was just a joke.

Comment: @Won't: I know, I didn't take that any offensive. There's nothing wrong with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange can only limit what Gravatar gets pulled for your account by rating (G, PG, R, X). Aside from that, it's Gravatar's call what images are acceptable for each category. If someone here had a problem with your avatar and wanted to report it, they'd go to Gravatar.

So, basically, anything that Gravatar would allow you to upload as a PG-rated (SE uses the PG rating for their Gravatars) image is "acceptable."