# Give other users a bit of your reputation (to say thankyou for an epic answer for which 10 is surely not enough)

Tags: feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Post-factum bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25933/post-factum-bounty)
>   [How come no option to ‘tip’ answerers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers)

I understand this could lead to possible corrupt behavior, but no more than the ability to create multiple users and go from IP to IP adding points to yourself. I got an answer from Clement on SO that was so epic that he deserves a bounty, but he answered it in like 30 minutes so obviously there was no bounty.

Comment: Just wait until you can post the bounty. Then post it and award it immediately to them.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25933/bounty-is-called-mounds-in-usa/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is not going to happen....

mgmt will say "if its good others will upvote it"

rep sacrifice opens up the system to gaming

Comment: @waffles I kind of figured that too, but my inspiration for the idea came from the idea that if somebody doesn't know how much reputation they might get for an epic answer, but it could be a lot :), even enough to buy a new house or more, they might give more epic answers in hopes of accomplishing their dreams.

Comment: P.S. You got 25 rep points from me :)

Comment: P.P.S Are you building your own version of stack overflow in Rails with Debian OS, using Perl, and Python? (went to your website)

Comment: @orokusaki its not exactly SO, but has the Q&A setup (and also a bug tracking / blog and uservoice feature requests) its built on rails with redis/sphinx. im looking for beta customers

Comment: Nice. I like the little "active wishes" part.