# Suggestion: Allow users accepting answers to allocate some of their rep to the answerer

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)
>   [Post-factum bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25933/post-factum-bounty)

I ask questions pretty regularly on stack overflow, and have got some really great answers.  Like the bounty scheme, perhaps there should be a mechanism where when you get a great answer, you can acknowledge it by giving a late bounty.  Just a thought.

Comment: Why yes you can: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25933/post-factum-bounty/

Comment: Yup, it seems to be a dup ok.  Feel free to delete.

Answer (score 5):

You can already do this if you haven't placed a bounty on your question already.  Simply add a bounty and award it to the user — [Improvements to the Bounty System](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).

Comment: +1, but you have to wait awhile to do this.  For example, I was going to test it by giving you some points, but alas I can't yet.  And by the time I can, I'll probably have forgotten about it and moved on.

Comment: there is that.  and i'm not sure if there's any forced delay between setting a bounty and accepting an answer; that wouldn't be desirable since it might lead others to think you were looking for better answers.

Comment: You can always add an outlook reminder @shane

Comment: @Downvoter ick.... if not getting a bounty means someone on this planet uses Outlook less, i don't really need those points!

Comment: ok ok, gmail reminder, alert on your phone/ipod/gadget of your choice, a post-it on your monitor, or asking a friend that uses outlook to give you a call in 48 hours.

Comment: @Downvoter - I use Thunderbird, so a yellow post-it is the best bet.  (As he clears a mound of old unread post-its to get through to the keyboard).