# Separate awarding of bounties from acceptance

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

Now that [setting bounties on other peoples questions is planned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/how-about-making-it-possible-to-set-up-bounty-on-someone-elses-question), I think it would make sense to separate the indication that a bounty has been awarded from the checkmark. (create a separate icon). Then the issue about auto-acceptance of answers could finally disappear, as the bounty and bounty icon could be automatically awarded instead of acceptance.

Additional possibilities that are **non-core**. It is not actually necessary to implement these possibilities, rather they are just listed as examples of what else would be possible once bounties were split off:

- Multiple bounties would become possible, with the proviso that one person cannot receive over 500 points from answering a single questions.
- 15 points of the bounty could be kept separate for the question owner to award

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And now, it is done. See, much better =P

Comment: You could always just not accept one, or take a hint from the community and accept the up-voted answer.

Comment: But that would be saying I agree with it, which I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, let's make it as complicated as humanly possible! That sounds like fun! :)

There are so many issues around multiple users pooling bounty awards on questions that we haven't even begun to think them through. This isn't coming for a while. Like 6 months+ a while.

edit: this is now completed.
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Comment: But after a 6+ months while, it can be implemented in 6-8 weeks

Comment: It'd be great if everyone pitched in 50 rep for the first question opened up to this. Imagine the windfall! The user with the winning answer would be asterisked by this rep gain to no end. Asterisk! Asterisk!

Comment: @random: Thats why I suggested a 500 rep limit

Comment: @Jeff: The base proposal is rather simple, the two dot points are only additional possibilities