# Someone started a bounty on my question. Is my reputation safe?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

Someone has opened a bounty onto one of my own questions.

What will happen if I accept an answer on this question? Whose reputation will be decreased?

Comment: Don't worry, not yours.

Comment: and for this bounty he offered he gets the [altruist](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/222/altruist) badge

Comment: Don't worry, be happy because this will create more traffic to your question.

Comment: I don't worry  :-))  I just wanted to know who was supposed to vote for the answer and who was supposed to give the reward to the winner :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a bounty is placed, the reputation is immediately taken from **the person who placed the bounty**. So, whatever you do - your reputation is safe =)

[This meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/how-about-making-it-possible-to-set-up-bounty-on-someone-elses-question) was the cause of the flexibility added to the bounty system and you can read about it in more detail on the [stackoverflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/). There's a paragraph that seems particularly relevant to your question (my emphasis):

> Once awarded, you’ll see the bounty amount icon permanently affixed to the answer it was awarded to — and, again, **all bounties are completely independent of and unrelated to accepting an answer**.

Answer (score 3):

The reputation of the person who opened the bounty has already been reduced (it gets taken as soon as the bounty has been opened).

You will not see any change in your reputation.

Answer (score 3):

The reputation of whoever offered the bounty will have decreased *when the user started the bounty*.

Answer (score 2):

One additional note: if the member who placed the bounty won't choose anyone to get the bounty within 7 days, it will be granted to the most upvoted answer **posted after the bounty was placed**, if such exists. (Otherwise it will just dissolve into the void)

Comment: who is supposed to accept the answer ? teh one who post the question, or the one who started the bounty ?

Comment: @Oliver, *you* accept your best answer. But the user who started the bounty gets to pick an answer independent of your choice. That answer will get the bounty awarded. This might be the same answer, or another.

Comment: @Oliver the reason behind such a thing is that the person who started the bounty found great interest in your question and want to see it answered - so it's all *his* doing, you're not directly involved. You can't affect who will get the bounty, except upvoting new answers.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the bounty not being taken from your rep, the increased visibility may well actually help your rep if it was a good question. I placed a bounty on someone else's month old question, scored +1 at the time and it ended up +9 at the end.