# Show an icon on questions that had an unawarded bounty

Tags: feature-request, design, bounties, expired-bounty

**Wouldn't it be interesting and handy to see an icon on questions that once had an unawarded bounty?**

I've been requesting the Stack Exchange team add this in surveys for several years now and thought I should formally request it and gauge what the general user base thinks.

It's not obvious without looking at the history or adding a bounty of the next higher reward.

The icon could be slightly different on questions [where a bounty was offered on someone else's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/how-about-making-it-possible-to-set-up-bounty-on-someone-elses-question).

The **purpose** to know it's unsolved and someone was trying very hard to get an answer to it.

Obviously answers with >= 2 get half the bounty, so this would be rare cases where the question eluded everyone who's seen it. Sort of like the [Tumbleweed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399).

Comment: "requesting the StackExchange Team add this in surveys for several years now" - huh? What surveys?

Comment: SO Developer Survey @Sha. Not exactly the place to do feature requests though...

Comment: But its been a question In the Yearly Surveys - the one's the guys share using cool infographics.

Comment: It's like "Leave us a feedback" boxes in places like McDonald's... nobody is really taking a look at those.

Comment: Ok, I will accept that as a NO. No harm caused suggesting things. -6 is reminiscent of the old meta.so days. Happy to walk away from this idea.

Answer (score 0):

What is the use for this icon?

> In that case I'm sure the community would reward it with more in upvotes in return.

So if I got you right, the sole purpose of this icon is to attract more upvotes. I don't think that is a valid reason to add this icon. Your answer should stand on its own and attract votes on its own. If you post an outstanding answer, I am sure you will get upvotes. We don't want users to pitty-upvote you because they think you missed out on something.

Comment: Its to bring attention that this is unsolved and someone was trying very hard to get an answer to it. Forget the *I'm sure the community would...* that was an assumption and not necessarily true - I only wrote that to counter the only negative point about this feature-request

Comment: Back then indeed. But now? Is someone still looking for an answer that desperately? If you know the answer, it doesn't matter if it has an expired bounty or not.

Comment: "I'm sure" and "an assumption". Which of both?

Comment: Ok I deleted that part of my question, sorry if it affects your answer.

Comment: So now the purpose of the icon is ...? You don't give any reason it should be there.

Comment: Edited question to clarify the purpose it isn't to pity me - I'm the 17th top bounty hunter on [so] and would love to be able to do a query or plainly see if a question was in desperate need of a solution. Cheers

Comment: Can you discuss this with me in this chat room? http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1049/realtime-sql-on-se-api